# Chkconfig alternative for Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, services

I've become very accustomed to managing service startups on Redhat/RHEL platforms using `chkconfig` though that doesn't appear to be the Debian/Ubuntu way - How do I update runlevel information for system services on Ubuntu?

Ultimately looking for the equivalents of:

```
chkconfig --add <service>
chkconfig --level 345 <service> on
chkconfig --del <service>
```

Comment: BTW: you can `apt-get install chkconfig` the package on ubuntu as well. However it is broken since years, the following symlink will make it (somewhat) work: `ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The equivalent to `chkconfig` is `update-rc.d`

The equivalents you seek are

```
update-rc.d <service> defaults
update-rc.d <service> start 20 3 4 5
update-rc.d -f <service>  remove
```

See [this useful page](https://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/) for more information or check out man update-rc.d

Comment: update-rc.d is *only* meant to be used in packaging scripts, not by humans.  It also is for init scripts, which Ubuntu doesn't use.  Ubuntu uses Upstart.

Comment: "Please  note  that  this  program  was  designed  for  use  in  package maintainer   scripts  and,  accordingly,  has  only  the  very  limited functionality required by such scripts.  System administrators are  not encouraged  to  use  update-rc.d to manage runlevels.  They should edit the links directly or use runlevel editors such as sysv-rc-conf and bum instead."

From the manpage:  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because the updated man pages have removed that warning. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

Comment: Which still doesn't change the fact that Ubuntu doesn't even use SysV init scripts nowadays and update-rc.d is only for them.

Comment: There are still some sysv scripts used and especially they do work with upstart as well. So if you did not had the time to convert a script you might still use it this way.

Comment: Current man page of `update-rc.d`:
" Older  versions of update-rc.d also supported start and stop options.  These options are no longer supported, and are now equivalent to the defaults option."

Comment: The link is dead :(

Answer (score 55):

Best alternative IMHO is sysv-rc-conf
To install just need to run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

Once installed run the command:

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf
```

You can check or uncheck the options to start a service on any level of execution and may even stop or start the services from this console. It is an indispensable tool to enable or disable applications on an permanently way to boot your ubuntu
If you need a quick change, then you can use the CLI interface:

For example to stop ssh at levels 3 and 5 of execution:

```
sysv-rc-conf-off level 35 ssh
```

Atd to start in runlevels 2,3,4 and 5:

```
sysv-rc-conf on atd
```

If you want to know more:

```
man sysv-rc-conf
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, except I did `sysv-rc-conf apache2 on` / `sysv-rc-conf apache2 off` etc.

Comment: This works for me compared update-rc.d which was looking for program scripts in /etc/init.d/ directory where some programs like vsftpd are not installed.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You have typo: `sysv-rc-conf-off level 35 ssh` should be `sysv-rc-conf --level 35 ssh off`

Comment: Tested working on **Ubuntu 16.04LTS**, where `update-rc.d` did not.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package sysv-rc-conf` on Ubuntu 18.04 for `sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf`

Answer (score 10):

Right now, there is no equivalent on a stable release for doing things with Upstart scripts.  Jacob Peddicord wrote jobservice (backend daemon) and jobs-admin (GTK+ GUI that talks to it) for his Google Summer of Code project.  Lucid packages are [in his PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jpeddicord/+archive/jobs).  They also exist in Universe in Maverick.  There is no command line front-end for jobservice yet, just jobs-admin.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
apt-get install chkconfig
```

This works, at least of as Ubuntu 12.04 release.

Comment: Doesn't work on 12.10

Comment: have 12.04, and apt-get install chkconfig gives: "E: Package 'chkconfig' has no installation candidate".  Whats in your /etc/apt/sources.list file?

Comment: Looks like the latest was published for precise: 12.04: 1.0-79.1-2 0 in `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages`. Some fixes never made it into a package.

Comment: No package on Ubuntu 14.04. Do we need to add another source?

Answer (score 6):

Lets walk from ZERO to Goal - how to do it with step by step.

**Step 1:** lets write a hello world

```
cat >> /var/tmp/python/server.py <<\EOF
#/usr/bin/python
import time
while True:
  print "hello> YES Bello"
  time.sleep(30)

EOF
```

**Step 2:** lets make our hello world application server.py automated

```
cat >> /var/tmp/myserver.sh <<\EOF
#!/bin/sh
script='/var/tmp/python/server.py'
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/python $script &

EOF
chmod +x /var/tmp/myserver.sh

cat >> /etc/init.d/myserver <<\EOF

#! /bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
DAEMON=/var/tmp/myserver.sh
PIDFILE=/var/run/myserver.pid

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
     log_daemon_msg "Starting feedparser"
     start_daemon -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
     log_end_msg $?
   ;;
  stop)
     log_daemon_msg "Stopping feedparser"
     killproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
     PID=`ps x |grep server.py | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
     kill -9 $PID       
     log_end_msg $?
   ;;
  force-reload|restart)
     $0 stop
     $0 start
   ;;
  status)
     status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON atd && exit 0 || exit $?
   ;;
 *)
   echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/atd {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}"
   exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0


EOF
chmod +x /etc/init.d/myserver
chmod -R 777 /etc/init.d/myserver
```

**Step 3:**

```
$ update-rc.d myserver defaults
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/myserver missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/myserver ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20myserver -> ../init.d/myserver
   /etc/rc1.d/K20myserver -> ../init.d/myserver
   /etc/rc6.d/K20myserver -> ../init.d/myserver
   /etc/rc2.d/S20myserver -> ../init.d/myserver
   /etc/rc3.d/S20myserver -> ../init.d/myserver
   /etc/rc4.d/S20myserver -> ../init.d/myserver
   /etc/rc5.d/S20myserver -> ../init.d/myserver
```

- So in step 3, the system on boot, will automatically execute the server.py as daemon and make it easy to automate

Hope it helped.

Comment: +1: Very useful answer but I think it has the wrong question attached to it.