# How to enable or disable services?

Tags: upstart, services

I read about how to enable and disable services in Ubuntu and it seems that there are different possibilities to manage them.

The first method I found is `update-rc.d` to add new services to startup, which aims on the `/etc/init.d` folder and its contents.

The other one I found is to edit `.conf` files in the `/etc/init` folder.

What's the recommended way to enable / disable / add services and why?

Could you please give a short bulletproof step by step example on how to add a service in Ubuntu and enable and disable it?

Comment: For networking please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/230698/how-to-restart-the-networking-service

Comment: [This](http://ryuslash.wordpress.com/2009/12/31/enablingdisabling-services-in-fedora-12/) would be helpful for those stuck on Fedora 12 and have landed here. In case linkrot `chkconfig` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that the answer for Ubuntu 14.04 is still missing here.

Comment: @MarcelloNuccio: Starting with Ubuntu 15.04, Upstart has been deprecated in favor of Systemd.

Comment: Auto-start programs are configured in `autostart` manifests or in `*.service` files in several locations, as well as in `init.d` or `crontab`. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525845/43233

Answer (score 987, accepted):

There are services that can be enabled/disabled using the GUI (like the `startup` application) or the terminal.

For the Terminal you have several options. First, open a terminal (Type "terminal" in the dash, for example, and open it). Then:

### Temporary enabling/disabling services

To stop and start services *temporarily* (Does not enable / disable them for future boots), you can type `service SERVICE_NAME [action]`. For example:

- `sudo service apache2 stop`: Will **STOP** the Apache service until Reboot or until you start it again.
- `sudo service apache2 start`: Will **START** the Apache service assuming it was stopped before.
- `service apache2 status`: Will tell you the STATUS of the service, if it is either enabled/running of disabled/NOT running.
- `sudo service apache2 restart`: Will **RESTART** the service. This is most commonly used when you have changed, a config file. In this case, if you changed either a PHP configuration or an Apache configuration. Restart will save you from having to stop/start with 2 command lines
- `service apache2`: In this case, since you did not mention the ACTION to execute for the service, it will show you all options available for that specific service. This aspect varies depending on the service, for example, with MySQL it would only mention that it is missing a parameter. For other services like networking service it would mention the small list of all options available.

### Systemd

Starting with Ubuntu 15.04, Upstart will be deprecated in favor of Systemd. With Systemd to manage the services we can do the following (through the `systemctl action SERVICE` pattern):

- `sudo systemctl start SERVICE`: Use it to start a service. Does not persist after reboot
- `sudo systemctl stop SERVICE`: Use it to stop a service. Does not persist after reboot
- `sudo systemctl restart SERVICE`: Use it to restart a service
- `sudo systemctl reload SERVICE`: If the service supports it, it will reload the config files related to it without interrupting any process that is using the service.
- `systemctl status SERVICE`: Shows the status of a service. Tells whether a service is currently running.
- `sudo systemctl enable SERVICE`: Turns the service on, on the next reboot or on the next start event. It persists after reboot.
- `sudo systemctl disable SERVICE`: Turns the service off on the next reboot or on the next stop event. It persists after reboot.
- `systemctl is-enabled SERVICE`: Check if a service is currently configured to start or not on the next reboot.
- `systemctl is-active SERVICE`: Check if a service is currently active.
- `systemctl show SERVICE`: Show all the information about the service.
- `sudo systemctl mask SERVICE`: Completely disable a service by linking it to `/dev/null`; you cannot start the service manually or enable the service.
- `sudo systemctl unmask SERVICE`: Removes the link to `/dev/null` and restores the ability to enable and or manually start the service.

### Upstart (Deprecated Since 15.04)

If we want to use the official Upstart way (Note that, for the moment, not all services have been converted to Upstart), we could use the following commands:

`status SERVICE` - This will tell us if a converted service is running or not. Note that this is deprecated in favor of `start`, `stop`, `status` & `restart`. It will also tell us if a service has not yet been converted to upstart:

A converted service would typically output the current status (Starting, Running, Stopping...) and process ID. A non converted service would give an error about an **unknown job**.

Some shortcuts may only work with the `service` command above but not with the commands below unless they are 100% converted to upstart services:

- `sudo start mysql`: Start
- `sudo stop mysql`: Stop
- `sudo restart mysql`: Restart
- `sudo status smbd`: Status

#### Enabling / Disabling a service

To toggle a service from starting or stopping permanently you would need to:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/SERVICE.override
```

where the stanza `manual` will stop Upstart from automatically loading the service on next boot. Any service with the `.override` ending will take precedence over the original service file. You will only be able to start the service manually afterwards. If you do not want this then simply delete the `.override`.
For example:

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/mysql.override
```

Will put the MySQL service into `manual` mode. If you do not want this, afterwards you can simply do

```
sudo rm /etc/init/mysql.override
```

and Reboot for the service to start automatically again. Of course to enable a service, the most common way is by installing it. If you install Apache, Nginx, MySQL or others, they automatically start upon finishing installation and will start every time the computer boots. Disabling, as mentioned above, will make use of the service `manual`.

Comment: Do you need to add `.service` to every command? `systemctl mongod status` worked just fine.

Comment: @DanDascalescu no you don't but let me clarify that there.

Comment: Should the .override file need to be placed in /etc/init.d/, i.e., where the service is placed?

Comment: Why Upstart is deprecated in 15.04 ? what is the right way to run scripts on start/restart in ubuntu 16.04 or later ?

Comment: @KamalakannanJ have you used the rc levels? (eg /etc/rc0.d) or /etc/rc.local?

Comment: @KamalakannanJ Ubuntu dropped `upstart` in favor of `systemd`, since that's what Debian switched to.  [Here's some fluff from Mark Shuttleworth about it.](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316)

Comment: For disabling a service at boot on a pre-systemd system I found the `/etc/init/FOO.override` to _not_ work. What works is `chmod -x /etc/init.d/FOO`.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. The `systemd` set of commands works a treat on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: But what if an upstart service does not start and I don't have an ``override`` file?

Comment: This would create 2 questions @PhilippLudwig - 1. How to debug upstart services and 2. Why am I missing the override status altogether (after trying to create it).

Comment: I wanted to disable a service (cups) permanently but neither approach worked by me

Comment: For future readers: there was also a tool `chkconfig`, where `chkconfig service on` for example enables the service.

Comment: This answer is missing a section on snap services. Run `sudo snap services` to see a list of them.

Answer (score 375):

Currently there are actually three different ways for software to be started as a service in Ubuntu, *SysV*, *Upstart* and *systemd*. A service is defined here as a program run by the system in the background, as opposed to one started and run directly by the user.

### SysV

The traditional way to start services in Linux was to place a script in `/etc/init.d`, and then use the `update-rc.d` command (or in RedHat based distros, `chkconfig`) to enable or disable it.

This command uses some mildly complicated logic to create symlinks in `/etc/rc#.d`, that control the order of starting services. If you run `ls /etc/rc2.d` you can see the order that services will be killed with a file name like `K##xxxx` and started with file names `S##xxxx`.  The `##` in `S##xxxx` means a "start order" for service `xxxx`.  Conversely, the `##` in `K##xxxx` means the kill order for service `xxxx`.

One major issue with *SysV* was that when booting the system, [everything had to be done in serial, one thing after another, making system boot times really slow](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#critique-of-the-system-v-init-system). Attempts were made to parallelize this, but they were haphazard and hard to take full advantage of. This was the main reason that *Upstart* was created.

### Upstart

Upstart uses job definition files in `/etc/init` to define on what events a service should be started. So, while the system is booting, upstart processes various events, and then can start multiple services in parallel. This allows them to fully utilize the resources of the system, for instance, by starting a disk-bound service up while another CPU-bound service runs, or while the network is waiting for a dynamic IP address to be assigned.

You can see all of the upstart job files by running `ls /etc/init/*.conf`

Let me just stop here and say that if you don't know what a service is, or what it does, DO NOT disable it!

Not all services have been converted to upstart. While working on the server team at Canonical for the past few months, I've worked on a number of converted job files, and the nicest part is that it allows one to get rid of all the script "magic" and just put in a few commands here and there to define exactly how to start the service, and nothing more. But for now, only a handful of traditional network services, like *squid* and *samba*, have been converted.

#### Is a service upstart-based?

In order to figure out if a service is upstart-based, you can run the status command:

```
status servicename
```

If it's an *upstart* job, it will show this:

```
$ status statd
statd start/running, process 942
```

But if it's not, you'll see something more like this:

```
$ status apache2
status: Unknown job: apache2
```

In this case, `apache2` has not been converted to *upstart*. So, to disable `apache2` you just run

```
sudo update-rc.d apache2 disable
sudo service apache2 stop
```

#### Disable services (jobs) in upstart

Upstart job definitions do not have an `update-rc.d` command. To disable the job, you need to edit the job file directly to disable it. There are two ways to do this.

If you want to still be able to manually start it, then you need to comment out the `start on` condition. Say you want to install *samba*, but not have it start automatically. Here is the job file (in natty):

```
description "SMB/CIFS File Server"
author      "Steve Langasek <steve.langasek@ubuntu.com>"

start on local-filesystems
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

pre-start script
    RUN_MODE="daemons"

    [ -r /etc/default/samba ] && . /etc/default/samba

    [ "$RUN_MODE" = inetd ] && { stop; exit 0; }

    install -o root -g root -m 755 -d /var/run/samba
end script

exec smbd -F
```

To disable *samba*, you can just put a `#` in front of the "`start on local-filesystems`". Note that while it won't start back up on boot, you still need to stop it this time with

```
sudo service smbd stop
```

If, however, you never want *samba* to start, I'd suggest actually removing the package. If, however, you want it installed, but not startable, you can also do:

```
mv /etc/init/smbd.conf /etc/init/smbd.conf.disabled
```

#### Disable a service using start/stop stanza (as of 11.04)

Starting with the version of upstart that will be in 11.04, there is a new keyword that disables the `start on` and `stop on` stanzas: `manual`. So another way to disable the service as of 11.04 is to do:

```
echo 'manual' | sudo tee /etc/init/mysql.override

# command from root shell
echo manual >> /etc/init/mysql.override
```

You can create an `override` file to disable a service without editing the job definition at all, by just putting the `manual` keyword in it.

Comment: Great, thanks. Finally figured out how to stop a couple of "mystery services", and enough that I can start experimenting with services on my own.

Comment: Looks like 11.04 has override too. So `echo manual >> /etc/init/<service>.override` is prefered as it leaves the original .conf filke intact. Anyway, its still a shame that such a basic enable/disable took 3 years to develop, and theres no GUI for that.

Comment: *update-rc.d* is what really matters

Comment: I assume that the `*.override` files are appended to `*.conf` files for computing the result *but* this is not documented anywhere. Another interpretation would be that `*.override` replaces the contents of `*.conf` but would break the `exec` and friends in the `*.conf` file.

Comment: seems to much mor ehandle the original topic than the answer that has been tagged as the defintive answer by the original question poster. Thanks! :)

Comment: In my case, the file `/etc/init/ssh.conf` exists but `status ssh` and `status sshd` both say "Unknown job".  This answer does not seem to address such a possibility?

Comment: `status ssh` gives me 'Unknown job', too, but `service ssh status` works for me

Comment: What about snap services? Run `sudo snap services` to see a list of them

Answer (score 133):

### sysv-rc-conf

Try using **sysv-rc-conf**

```
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

and to start managing the services, execute

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf
```

Which will bring up interactive window like this

[image]

You can further navigate through pages using `Ctrl+n` for next page and `Ctrl+p` for previous page. You can enable and disable services by selecting `SPACE` on desired runlevels.

### Jobs-Admin

Another alternate would be  **Jobs-Admin** by installing through

```
sudo apt-get install jobs-admin
```

Which also provides GUI like this

[image: jobs-admin preview]

For showing more jobs , you have to tick the **Show Protected Jobs** from its menu.

### chkconfig

And third option would be **chkconfig**,

```
sudo apt-get install chkconfig
```

It can be used via CLI `chkconfig`, showing list of On/Off jobs.
Also we can view system services using `chkconfig –list`

Services can be turned on using

```
chkconfig <service> on
```

Services can be turned off using

```
chkconfig <service> off
```

And we can even add our own service, using a proper init script with proper headings.

```
chkconfig --add <service>
```

### update-rc.d

And another option can be referred [here update-rc.d](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/update-rc.d.8.html) , explained briefly [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2263/chkconfig-alternative-for-ubuntu-server).

Note that for Ubuntu Server 12.04, `update-rc.d` [is used instead of chkconfig.](https://askubuntu.com/a/2265/109148)

Comment: on ubuntu server: `Package chkconfig is not available, but is referred to by another package.`

Comment: @pwned You are free to edit and post the updated info regarding server edition.Thank you.

Comment: I did as you have suggested, now it is up for peer review.

Comment: **jobs-admin** doesn't allow to change jobs (Ubuntu 14.04), producing a crash report instead ;-)

Comment: sysv-rc-conf isn't suitable for use with upstart or systemd, it patently being only for the old System 5 rc system, which hasn't been the default on Ubuntu Linux for almost a decade. Debian Bug #791689 acknowledges this and questions why it hasn't been marked as conflicting with systemd.

Comment: [sysv-rc-conf](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+source/sysv-rc-conf) has no current release in 17.04 Zesty

Answer (score 50):

For those of us who run Ubuntu over ssh, I think the nicest option is `rcconf` - a text based program:

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
sudo rcconf
```

[image]

Navigate with tab and arrow keys, press spacebar to enable/disable. Changes are persistent across restarts.

Screenshot borrowed from [this blogpost](http://www.bergek.com/2009/02/22/control-debian-daemons/), which also shows `sysv-rc-conf` - a similar tool that also lets you set the runlevel. (For those who happen to care enough about runlevels to wish to change them :)

Unfortunately, rcconf doesn't work with upstart (services listed in `/etc/init/*`), just with the traditional mechanism (`ls -l /etc/init.d/*` - the ones that are not symbolic links).

Fortunately, many of the services that are relevant when ssh-ing in to a server (Apache, Tomcat, mdadm, boinc-client...) haven't been moved to upstart yet.

Comment: Does this still work with upstart?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But it has worked for all the cases I have wanted to change - the upstart jobs seems to be mostly things I never want to disable - hardware clock, log daemon, network etc. (on Ubuntu server, at least). But it's something to be aware of (I wasn't :), I've updated the post.

Comment: Unfortunately mysql was converted to upstart. And thats a service i only use when im doing some project.

Comment: There's a bug with rcconf on Ubuntu 12.04 that prevents the program from starting. To solve the issue you need to install the dialog package.

Comment: @devius you can also work around that bug using `sudo ln -s /bin/whiptail /usr/bin/whiptail`

Comment: Since this answer was written, `update-rc.d` was changed, and [some of its deprecated functionality was removed](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2013/05/msg01109.html).  Debian bug #727735 notes that rcconf was not changed to match.  And no, rcconf does not work with systemd either, thus not being applicable to either of the default init systems for Ubuntu Linux for the past decade.

Answer (score 19):

I found out that [up to bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jobs-admin&searchon=names) there is this GUI tool, something like BUM but compatible with Upstart: Jobs-Admin

```
sudo apt-get install jobs-admin
```

Comment: But it is too simple, and do not allow to change "protected jobs" ( what is that jobbs? Apple has Jobs, operating system has daemons!)

Comment: I doesn't even allow to change "unprotected jobs" (Ubuntu 14.04), producing a crash report instead ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Editing the existing upstart configuration file (as described above) is not such a good idea. An updated package could provide an updated config, and you'd had to repeat your changes over and over.

By taking a look at `man 5 init` one will find a more appropriate solution: using an override config. Short example: Say we have a service called "foobar", so there would be a file called `/etc/init/foobar.conf` with its upstart configuration. Now you don't want to remove that file, nor to modify it -- but neither you want this service to run? So place an *override* file next to it: `/etc/init/foobar.override`, containing (optionally the header with the description and) instead the `start on` / `stop on` lines you place a line with one word: `manual`. This way you tell upstart to basically use the `foobar.conf`, but override the startup definition to only start that service when manually enforced (via `service foobar start` in our example).

Answer (score 9):

There is also the **Boot-Up Manager**.

To install: `sudo apt-get install bum`

Further info: http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html

[image]

Comment: Dont forget to check the "Advanced" button.

Comment: no any releases for arm64?

Comment: @Vitalicus I don't know much about arm64. 1) KDE Plasma (which supports arm64 architecture) has System Settings > Background Services, 2) It might be be possible to build Stacer: https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer

Comment: @Vitalicus I've just found Stacer (which offers the same feature as well as many other system maintenance functions) in official Debian repositories supporting arm64: https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/stacer OR https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/stacer

Answer (score 6):

Simplest method for me as I use CLI only is `update-rc.d`.

To enable or disble auto-start on reboot etc :

```
sudo update-rc.d <daemon|service> <enable|disable>
```

Example:

```
update-rc.d spamassassin enable
```

To stop or start a daemon or check its status:

```
sudo service <daemon|service> <start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status>
```

Example:

```
sudo service spamassassin status
  spamassassin.service - Perl-based spam filter using text analysis
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/spamassassin.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-05-21 13:04:10 SAST; 4s ago
  Process: 1928 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
 Main PID: 1949 (spamd)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 2361)
   CGroup: /system.slice/spamassassin.service
           ├─1949 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid --create-prefs --max-child
           ├─1951 spamd child
           └─1952 spamd child`  etc  etc
```

`update-rc.d` can do a little more than the basic shown above:

```
usage: update-rc.d [-f] <basename> remove
       update-rc.d [-f] <basename> defaults
       update-rc.d [-f] <basename> defaults-disabled
       update-rc.d <basename> disable|enable [S|2|3|4|5]
        -f: force
```

As always; you van refer [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/sysv-rc/update-rc.d.8.en.html).

Answer (score 2):

I use [Stacer](https://oguzhaninan.github.io/Stacer-Web/):

> Stacer is an open source system optimizer and application monitor that helps users to manage entire system with different aspects, its an all in one system utility.

It shows services and processes also. A complete GUI system toolbox.