# How to enable SSH server in recovery mode?

Tags: ssh

How to enable SSH server in Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop Edition recovery mode?
My display is not working (broken video card). So how can I do that "blindly"? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know what you're typing onto, it's just one simple command, but I'll explain the complete procedure to rule out any and all errors.

1. Boot up the machine, holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>
2. When you're sure the grub menu is up, press <kbd>Down</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd>*
3. Press <kbd>Down</kbd> **six** times to select "Drop to root shell prompt" and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>
4. Carefully type `apt-get install openssh-server` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>
5. Carefully type `/etc/init.d/ssh start` and hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to start it without rebooting

The last step may not be required, but it doesn't hurt either.

*: Assuming your second boot entry is the recovery mode of the newest kernel, this may vary if you've manually put a Windows boot entry on top of the list or something like that, I assume you know.

If you decide to try "ssh" instead of "openssh-server", you may have to press "Y" to confirm. However, you don't need to enter the password if you drop to a root shell. After waiting long enough (!), hit Ctrl+C *in case* you didn't need to put in the "Y" before you continue.

Comment: Stefano Palazzo, You were right, all your instructions were correct. I've logged in from remote computer to a Ubuntu 10.10 :) How nice is that! :) I'm going to have a server - remote controlled laptop with broken video card. That's the reason why everyone should install Ubuntu at least as a second OS. :)

Comment: Hey awesome! :-)

Answer (score -1):

after you log in with a user you can type

```
$ sudo apt-get install ssh
```

type your password and enter

try to connect from another PC