# How to save Ubuntu from restarting on a laptop with malfunctioning video card?

Tags: kubuntu, intel-graphics

My laptop's video card is malfunctioning. I have Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop. After typical boot up, it restarts, but it's working fine in recovery mode.

There is my other solved question here:
[How to enable SSH server in recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22013/how-to-enable-ssh-server-in-recovery-mode/22017#22017)

I don't want my Ubuntu run in recovery mode. I want everything start normally, just without video card. I'm expecting it to run like a remote server.

Comment: I've copied my kernel log. I've tried few times to boot up Ubuntu normally, but it restarted. Probably because of graphics card. What should I look for in this log?

Comment: Today's kernel log: http://p.defau.lt/?xo9P4IvidnDNt34x3VNSSA

Comment: whole 2MB kernel.log file copy-paste: http://p.defau.lt/?TaBghp86SbJZeWzoVBaWOw

Comment: By the way, http://p.defau.lt is a great tool to copy-paste! :)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? .... 1) Is your graphics card broken or is it a driver/setup problem? 2) Do you want to start Ubuntu in console mode instead of gdm/kde?

Comment: Luri is right, my video card is broken and it malfunctions. Sometimes it shows graphics, sometimes not - the screen goes black or vertical colorful lines. I'm sure it's problem with video card. So I want to start Ubuntu in console mode and SSH would be started and I would be able to "apt-get install" new software and start various services which are accessible remotely via browser. I think, I'll launch some torrent downloader, FTP server, maybe some application server like Tomcat/Weblogic etc... That would be other question for what task I could use it.. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable SSH server in recovery mode?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22013/how-to-enable-ssh-server-in-recovery-mode)

Comment: This question is different, because now I want to know how to disable it from restarting when it starts in normal way, not a recovery mode. It probably restarts because it tries to load graphic card which is not working properly.

Comment: @ViliusK The way this site works is that you keep updating your original question with information, don't stick it in the comments, they just get buried, comments are for asking people to clarify, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the computer in recovery mode, when you get to the selection screen you need to select `root with networking`.

Once on the command line you can install and run the openssh-server:

```
apt-get install openssh-server
service ssh start
```

Although this won't help you with your graphics problem, it will let you get access to the machine.

Comment: This was described already by Stefano here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22013/how-to-enable-ssh-server-in-recovery-mode/22017#2201

Sorry if my questions was unclear.

Comment: Please delete your duplicate question.