# How to avoid mysqld to start on boot

Tags: boot, startup, mysql, services

In my laptop I have installed a LAMP environment for developing PHP apps. I would like to prevent these services (Apache, Mysql,..) starting on boot.

For apache is pretty simple to avoid it:
sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove

but for mysqld I couldn't find a way to do the same.

I have googled it for a couple of days trying to get a solution for this but I didn't found it.

Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the recommend way to enable / disable services?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommend-way-to-enable-disable-services)

Answer (score 8):

Are you using `mysql-server-5.1` from ubuntu repos?

In the file `/etc/init/mysql.conf` you will find some line like the following:

```
start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]
```

Moving the '2' from start to stop should do the trick:

```
start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [345])
stop on runlevel [0126]
```

Comment: In general you can just comment out the whole "start on" statement if you don't want a service to be started at boot time.

Comment: Great answer and nice question! Thanks, it is solved my problem.

Comment: Note that in Ubuntu 11.04 and later you can also do this without editting the file directly by adding /etc/init/mysql.override and adding the keyword 'manual'