# Prevent/stop wpa_supplicant from starting

Tags: wireless, configuration, services

wpa_supplicant seems to somehow be auto started at boot.

```
# ps auxwww |grep wpa
root       915  0.0  0.0  28824  1232 ?        S    17:36   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s
```

How do I disable this service, prevent it from auto starting ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be enough to remove the file

`/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant.service`

Move it somewhere so you can restore it, rather than immediately delete it. ;-)

Comment: For Ubuntu 13.04, I have to move the file ```fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.service```

Comment: Seems to still be the case for Ubuntu 15.10, which uses systemd.  wpa_supplicant is started from dbus, not from init scripts directly: `systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` shows it's running, but not auto-started by systemd directly.  (So [disabling for future boots](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services) isn't possible with `systemctl`).  Also,  `dpkg-divert` will keep it disabled across package upgrades.

Answer (score 10):

**Update for 2019**

htorque's solution did not work for me.

However, the following did work:

```
sudo systemctl disable wpa_supplicant
```