# How do I disable SSHD from starting automatically?

Tags: sshd

After installing openssh-server, the server start every time I boot. If I want it to be manual what do I need to do?

In version 0.6.7+ of upstart I would add a "manual" stanza to the job file.

10.04 has upstart 0.6.5-8. What is the preferred way to disable ssh from starting automatically in this case?

Answer (score 34):

Rename /etc/init/ssh.conf to /etc/init/ssh.conf.disabled.

```
sudo mv /etc/init/ssh.conf /etc/init/ssh.conf.disabled
```

Comment: Fast, easy and self-documenting. Perfect.

Comment: Possibly even better than `echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/ssh.conf.override` , see also [how-to-enable-or-disable-services](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Comment: `echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/ssh.conf.override` seems like a much better answer, because `sudo mv /etc/init/ssh.conf /etc/init/ssh.conf.disabled` also prevents starting the server manually without changing it back every time.

Comment: @BrianZ `ssh.conf.override` does not work for me, `ssh.override` instead.

Comment: This is not the recommended way. You're not telling the OS that the service is not supposed to run.  Use `update-rc.d` (or equivalent) to do that.

Comment: Did not work for me - Linux Mint 18.3 (based on Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Great it works for me.

Answer (score 23):

This should be enough,:

```
 update-rc.d ssh enable # sets the default runlevels to on 
 update-rc.d ssh disable # sets all to off
```

Comment: Does this work with an upstart job or just old sys v init scripts?

Comment: This should be enough, even if you're using upstart (dependency-base booting)

Comment: It says `System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/ssh do not exist.`

Answer (score 10):

In your /etc/init/ssh.conf, comment out the **start on** line:

```
# ssh - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
#
# The OpenSSH server provides secure shell access to the system.

description     "OpenSSH server"

#start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 10 5
umask 022
```

Comment: I'm of the opinion that in general it's better to use the more generic mechanisms that @komputes and hhlp mention.  Though this is fine for a single case.

Answer (score 9):

For system having `systemd` the proper way to do it is

```
sudo systemctl disable ssh.service
```

then

```
sudo systemctl stop ssh.service
```

Comment: This broke my `sshd` on 16.04: after that command `systemctl enable ssh.service` reports "File not found" and I had to purge and reinstall sshd to get it working.

Comment: You can start the service with `sudo systemctl start ssh.service` and use `systemctl status ssh.service` to see if it running or not.

Answer (score 8):

**note to the reader:**

for me (ubuntu 14.xx) only Bryan Agee's answer worked:
/etc/init/ssh.conf: comment out the "start on filesystem or runlevel..." line

**why won't the others do?**

> sudo mv /etc/init/ssh.conf /etc/init/ssh.conf.disabled

will result in completly *deactivating* the service. It is then not startable through "service ssh start" anymore.

> update-rc.d ssh enable # sets the default runlevels to on

does simply not work (perhaps uses different autostart routine)

> /etc/init/ssh.conf.override with "manual"

simply doesnt work

> touch /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

also completly disables the system

> sudo apt-get install bum

nice software, but it doesn't show ssh, so nothing to do here

person questioning:
    why are the above answeres even here? is the start system so complicated or does nobody tries his solutions? oO

Comment: And we're only talking about Ubuntu 14.04. Now try to find a universal solution...

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

Start `bum` with administrative privileges, disable openssh-server, confirm it, done.

Answer (score 3):

For versions with ssh started by upstart, run `touch /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run`. The upstart init script checks for this file and, if existent, does not start sshd.

Answer (score 3):

The manual method provided `/etc/init/ssh.config`.override method does not work for me using Ubuntu 14.04.03. `sshd` still starts automatically.

The `/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run` method prevents manual `sshd` start.

I had to use Brian Agee's method of removing the "start on" on line of `/etc/init/ssh.conf`. Then to manually start `sshd`:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and here's what I did about it. It's a bit of a hack, perhaps, but it works well enough, and you don't need to compromise the program in any way. Put the following in your crontab:

```
@reboot sudo service ssh stop
```

This tells `cron` to stop `ssh` every time you turn on your computer. Using `ssh` to connect to another computer isn't affected, as this only turns off the server service. And if you want to re-enable it for a short while, all you have to do is:

```
sudo service ssh start
```

Just remember to turn it back off when you're done!

Comment: This works on my Xubuntu 16.04 system which, of course, uses `systemd`. I don't believe this will work on pre-systemd Ubuntu systems.

Comment: Instead of making a cron-job, the proper way would be to disable it with `sudo systemctl disable sshd.service`, yet as you yourself mentioned your init system is way different to the one in the question. all relevant info about older init systems can be found in the first two answers in this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services#19324