# Disable automatic starting of sshd?

Tags: ssh, services, openssh, sshd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable SSH from starting automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56753/how-do-i-disable-ssh-from-starting-automatically)

Simple question here; what's the correct way to stop the sshd service from starting when the OS boots ?  I'm not sure if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/56755/31592) is correct, so I'm hoping some guru(s) can help me out!

What I'd like is a configuration that (after boot) allows me to start the service using `sudo service ssh start` when necessary.

Version info:

```
me@home:~$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
me@home:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: Useful answers at http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the service from startup with:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f sshd remove
```

Reset it with:

```
sudo update-rc.d sshd defaults
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by remove and reset...  Will I still be able to start the service manually?  (i.e. with `sudo service ssh start` ) ?

Comment: Yes, look more into services, runlevels, and rc.d scripts.

Comment: It looks like this isn't exactly the solution I'm looking for:
`me@home-computer:~$ sudo update-rc.d -f sshd remove`
 `Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/sshd ...`
`me@home-computer:~$ sudo reboot`

When my computer restarted, I was able to ssh to localhost without starting the service:

`me@home-computer:~$ ssh me@localhost`
`me@localhost's password: ***`
`Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04...`

I'm looking for a way to simply stop the service from starting automatically.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you try the answer you posted in your question? That is another option. Probably a good one.

Comment: I didn't post an answer in my question, not sure what you mean?

Comment: This does not work on ubuntu 14.04.  See `upstart` and `/etc/init/ssh.conf` [how-to-enable-or-disable-services](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Answer (score 1):

You could install [Boot-Up Manager](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html). It is a GUI to enable or disable services on startup.

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

It has to be run as root user.

```
sudo bum
```

[image]