# Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS includes unknown SFTP server

Tags: server, ftp, sftp

I've installed Ubuntu Server 14.04, and when I try to connect it with browser sftpd://10.0.0.100 it lets me see my files after I type my username and password.

It's weird, because I haven't installed any FTP server on my computer.

So, the question is: how to remove that FTP server that is running on my computer for some reason?

Comment: [STFP](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) ≠ [FTP](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable SSHD from starting automatically?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56753/how-do-i-disable-sshd-from-starting-automatically)

Comment: FTP over SSL is called FTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## SFTP is not FTP

**It stands for [SSH File Transter Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)**

Server users often **remotely connect** to the server using Secure Shell (SSH), also known as [OpenSSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH). Open SSH is part of the default Ubuntu server installation. SFTP is an extension of the [Secure Shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) protocol (SSH) version 2.0 to provide secure file transfer capabilities.

You can remove the openSSH server from your Ubuntu server, but then you will lose the ability to log into your server remotely using SSH protocol. If you are sure that you will never remotely connect to the server, and want to do this use the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server
```

Alternately you may disable SSHD to auto-start when your server starts up. See [How do I disable SSHD from starting automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56753/how-do-i-disable-sshd-from-starting-automatically). Thanks to [David Foerster](https://askubuntu.com/users/175814/david-foerster) for the link.

You may also want to learn about [How to harden an SSH server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2271/how-to-harden-an-ssh-server) so that it is not easy for a hacker to gain access to your server remotely.

Hope this helps