# how to drop " all " ssh connections in ubuntu?

Tags: ssh

This is for specified source:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -s 10.10.10.10 -j DROP
```

how to do this for all incoming ssh requests?

Comment: So you want to prevent people from `ssh-ing` into your machine ?

Comment: yeah, this is what i want

Comment: Look into this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/56849/295286

Comment: Stop your ssh server

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 easy ways to stop someone from being able to ssh to a machine.

1st. with iptables leave off the `-s` option. That denotes the source. if you use `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j DROP` that will block all connections to port 22.

2nd. as mentioned int he comments stop and disable the openssh-server. There are several ways to do that.

You can uninstall openssh-server,

rename the init.d/ssh.conf,

run `update-rc.d ssh disable`, or

use the method https://askubuntu.com/a/56849/295286

Comment: thx first one was exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Provided `ufw` is install, you can type the following on the terminal:

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo sudo ufw deny ssh
```

To check if the firewall is active:

```
sudo ufw status
```

You can also block the port `ssh` is using:

```
sudo ufw deny 22/tcp
```

To delete the rule if you don't need it any more:

```
sudo ufw delete deny ssh
```

[Reference Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)