# Run command at boot as root

Tags: boot, xubuntu, root

I need to run a bash script at boot-time as superuser in Xubuntu. I don't know where to start. I have to do something described in a Arch Linux guide. That guide says exactly:

> Add following at the end of the file : /etc/rc.sysinit

```
# Do my action
/etc/rc.d/do_my_action

/bin/dmesg >| /var/log/dmesg.log
```

But I do not have `/etc/rc.sysinit` and `/etc/rc.d/` in Xubuntu. I'm sure there are equivalent ones, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file you want is `/etc/rc.local`. This script will be run near or at the end of the boot process. Thus, everything should be up by this time.

However, as @bodhi.zazen pointed out, [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) might be the best option for you. [Check it out](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

**Note 1**: in 15.04 and later, Ubuntu uses `systemd` and not Upstart. Therefore if you want to take a service approach, see [this answer here by @muru](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up/719157#719157)

**Note 2**: In 16.10 there is no `/etc/rc.local` by default, but if you create it and make it executable (`sudo chmod u+x /etc/rc.local`) it will work because there is a systemd service to pull it in if it exists. Don't forget to put a line with `exit 0` at the end of the file to prevent any failed commands causing the entire boot process to hang.

Comment: So, I've just to put that code here? For now, that file contains only `exit 0`. And if I can ask, on boot when `rc.local` is executed, is the filesystem ready so I can also write a log somewhere for that command I want to run?

Comment: It sounds as if you are trying to run a boot (init) script. Ubuntu uses upstart. rc.local will run a command, or series of commands on boot and may or may not be your best option. What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @lorenzo-s: See my edit.

Comment: You may also find this answer helpful: http://askubuntu.com/a/20347/3940

Comment: It worked as you suggested, Scott. But the problem is that during boot `/etc/rc.local` cannot found command `my_script`, that is in `/usr/local/bin` and works on my user session.

Comment: Ok, I solved moving `my_script` from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin`. I'm also able to save log in `/var/log` using `my_script &>> /var/log/my_script`. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you create `/etc/rc.local` remember to add `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning. In my case it is not running without it.