# Autostart a service as root

Tags: bash, root, services, autostart

How to autostart a task at system start up i.e. **myprogram.bin** with admin rights?

Regards

Comment: What is a 'user task...with admin rights'?  Does that mean a root task? Or something else? Do you want it to run before login? Or after? Does your program need access to a display, keyboard, network, filesystem, or anything else? Does it produce output, and where should output go to?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: Jupp a root task!

Comment: Version 16 Plus

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to run a command with root privileges at reboot is to put it in the root 'cron' using the special time @reboot. To do this, execute the command:

`sudo crontab -e`

And add a line

`@reboot /path/to/myprogram.bin`

You could append `2>&1 > /path/to/log_file.txt` to send all output and error messages to a log file. By default, outputs from cron jobs are emailed to the root user which tends not to be terribly useful. Or you could configure your server to forward root emails to your own account.

Comment: Hi, and by using rc.local? Just putting there the path to myprogram?

Comment: What do you mean by 'and by using rc.local'? Please give more details.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/88589/run-command-at-boot-as-root

Comment: I see the link. What is your question?

Comment: How to this this by using rc.local'? Just put the path of ma program into it to run it at system startup?