# How to make Google Chrome not start as service?

Tags: google-chrome, services, autostart

I found Google Chrome running as service after I installed it, at each reboot.
This would not be a problem, if it won't eath 100% cpu. I would not like to uninstall it, but I'll be forced to do that if I can't find a way to disable its remain in memory as a service.

I couldn't find anything in Boot-Up-Manager, so I'm asking where to search...

Comment: How do you know that it runs as service? Can you show some evidence.

Comment: In system monitor I see the process as `chrome --type=service`

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommend-way-to-enable-disable-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this command s in terminal

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart/

sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop
```

And do a reboot , click the top Right-Corner Settings icon , to select Startup Applications.

[image]

If Google Chrome is present in list there , just Unselect to stop Autostarting it.

Comment: They show there again if I disable their autostart. See above.

Answer (score 7):

Do you have "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" ticked? If so, try unticking the box and then remove Google Chrome from the Startup Menu.

Also check to see if you have any sort of "notifications" such as GMail or messaging that may be causing the browser to be "always on".

[image: Background apps]

Comment: It seems this did not help. Both services readd themselves to start apps upon reboot...

Comment: I'm editing my answer to include the notifications part.

Comment: How can I be sure that GMail notification (I do have it in autostart) is responsible of Chrome and Chromium start as services and moreover, how can I get rid of this behaviour?

Comment: I don't use GMail notifications. Could you temporarily uninstall it to see if the problem goes away and that way at least be sure what is the source of your problem? Still, it's very unusual that something should take 100% CPU usage and it's indicative of something not working as it should! Unfortunately, the format of Ask Ubuntu doesn't seem to favor prolonged discussion so troubleshooting is difficult. You could sign up at ubuntuforums.org which is a bit less restrictive.

Comment: I removed GMail notifications from autostart, but after a few reboots, Chromium service added itself again to autostart apps.

Answer (score 3):

I had cloud print enabled which caused it.  Try disconnecting any cloud print printers you may be sharing from this computer.  In vasa1's pic, if you're sharing any printers, under Google Cloud Print, instead of 'Add Printers' there will be a button for disconnecting printers.  Hit that and then also make sure you have background apps unchecked (off).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to go to terminal to do this. There is an app called Startup Applications, which you can find by pressing the 9 dots in the corner and typing "Startup". Then, if Google Chrome is selected, unselect it and click "remove". That's all! It should stop opening chrome every time you log in. ;D