# How do I make Chromium use Flash from Google Chrome?

Tags: flash, google-chrome, chromium

Now, that Adobe has stopped issuing new releases for Linux desktops, the only option for users is to use Google Chrome, for those who want to use the latest Flash updates.
I use Chromium. Is there any way to get Chromium use the Flash from Google Chrome?
The reason I as this question is that I have noticed both these browsers run in the background, so technically, the browsers' plugins are available to use.

Comment: Please could you explain what you mean by "both these browsers run in the background" and how that is relevant to using the browsers' plugins?

Comment: unlike previous versions of firefox and google-chrome, latest version of chrome and chromium starts up as soon as you login to the desktop; it then keeps running in the background. so, i was thinking, if there is a way to make use of that and call the Pepper Flash plugin from Chromium.

Comment: Does Chrome start as soon as you login because you have "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" ticked in Chrome's `settings` (advanced)? See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158216/how-to-make-google-chrome-not-start-as-service/158279#158279) for an image.

Comment: yes it is. but thats not my concern. i was asking if we can use the latest flash pluin from Chrome.

Comment: This link was provided by user [BN-TX](http://askubuntu.com/users/271029/bn-tx) in a deleted answer: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/pepper-flash-player-installer-for.html

Comment: Why not just use Chrome?  I pulled my hair out with browser Flash issues for years.  Finally you can just use Chrome and not worry.  So why worry?  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pepperflashplugin-nonfree` is deprecated on 05/2015. They do not work for Chrome 53 and higher. You can see [Getting-Flash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash).
Ubuntu Wiki also "recommended" you to install `adobe-flashplugin`. Then we install `adobe-flashplugin`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Then you should restart your browser and open `chrome://plugins/`. If you don't see Adobe Flash Player there, you can run the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will upgrade `adobe-flashplugin` for chromium or if you use chrome, do it the same way.

Comment: Chrome does not need a `adobe-flashplugin`. It has built-in Flash.

Answer (score 24):

**THIS ANSWER IS 4 YRS OLD AND MAY NOT WORK ON NEWER SYSTEMS**

Download Google Chrome and extract `libpepflashplayer.so` from `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash` in the Chrome deb file
Copy `libpepflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins`
Make the necessary changes to the Chromium startup

```
sudo gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

Add this to the `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=11.5.31.2"
```

You can get the correct version of the flash plugin from the `"version":` json tag in the `mainfest.json` from `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash` in the Chrome deb file

Comment: Any tip to check what flash player am I running? :)

Comment: i did this and it does not seem to have worked . . .

Comment: It works thanks! Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Chromium 52.0.2743.116, PepperFlash 23.0.0.162

Comment: You can use the latest flash player direct from adobe with this method. https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect

Comment: @s3m3n The version will be in the `manifest.txt` file that should come with the PepperFlash distribution. When downloading PepperFlash directly from Adobe's website, `manifest.txt` is included in the `.tar.gz` file you download.

Comment: @villapx nowadays flash is off everywhere, but still thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

These instructions will install Pepper flash player for Chromium in Ubuntu 14.04 and later releases, and it will also be updated automatically. Because Google ended support for Chrome on 32-bit Linux in March, 2016, Pepper flash player can only be installed for 64-bit versions of Chromium.

To install flash player in Chromium web browser search the Dash for Software & Updates and open the Software & Updates window. Click the *Other Software* tab in the Software & Updates window and put a check mark in the checkbox to the left of where it says: **Canonical Partners**.

[image]

Click the *Close* button to close the Software & Updates window.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree # remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree if it's installed  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin  
sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

Comment: This does go along https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash which says it `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` is deprecated for `adobe-flashplugin`, but it just didn't work on Ubuntu 16.10 :-(

Answer (score 2):

This worked great for me:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/how-to-make-chromium-use-flash-player.html

It's similar to Craig's answer but with help for the "flags" part.

Comment: Nice! Please add a summary to your answer, just in case anything happens to the external link.

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome's flash player Pepper Flash is now in Ubuntu reposistories (Ubuntu 14.04). You can install it running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Restart Crhomium.

Comment: these commands do not work for me.  i get an error message that i should be using `dpkg`.  i'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.10: `ERROR: failed to retrieve status information from google`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm unable to comment because I'm new to Ask Ubuntu. The accepted answer is not accurate any more because Google stopped packaging flash player with its deb/rpm bundle. Go to Adobe download page here: http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/

Choose PPAPI version and download archive. You will find `libpepflashplayer.so` and `mainfest.json` required for following instructions in the accepted answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the `libflashplayer.so` from `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash` to `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins`.

Comment: unfortunately, it didnt work! :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by thangdc94,`pepperflashplugin-nonfree` is now deprecated and one should use `adobe-flashplugin` instead.

This works for a recent version of Chromium (version 62).

1. Install `adobe-flashplugin` package

   ```
   sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
   ```
2. Open chromium and go to address `chrome://settings/content/flash`. Make sure that the switch `Ask first (recommended)` is activated. If flash is still not working on some sites, you may need to whitelist them by addind their address to the `Allow` list.

Comment: Note that in earlier versions the settings were on page `chrome://plugins/`, but that does not exist anymore.

Answer (score -1):

There in no need to use flash from Google Chrome. You can simply install it from command line.

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Wait until finished. Then restart your browser and enjoy.

Comment: thats not   what i am asking for. please read the whole question

Comment: There are now **two** Flash plug-ins: one, the one obtained by using the command you suggest, will have only security updates. The other, Pepper Flash, is provided by Google along with each installation of Google Chrome and will have security updates and new or improved features. What OP wants to do is to have the **Chromium** browser use this second plug-in.