# Cannot use Flash in Chromium

Tags: lubuntu, google-chrome, flash, chromium

I need to use YouTube. I have Flash enabled in Chromium's settings, but it always says "could not load shockwave". I am running Lubuntu 13.04

Comment: That sounds like a bug in chrome, or a case of you not having Flash installed anywhere...

Comment: Are you sure you are using Google Chrome or Chromium?

Comment: i am using chromium

Comment: See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/158388/how-do-i-make-chromium-use-flash-from-google-chrome?rq=1

Comment: and by the way, flash in linux will stop working in April. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/chromium-npapi-flash-dropped-april-2014

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Erich E. Hoover and his team you can use [Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html#section_2_3) to run Flash, Shockwave, Silverlight and Unity Player in your native Ubuntu browsers.

The steps, reproduced here:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable flash
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `lubuntu-restricted-extras`. If you haven't, please do so along with the "recommends". In other words, run:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras
```

but don't run

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-restricted-extras
```

unless you really know what you're doing.

> Installing this package will pull in support for Microsoft fonts,
>   **Flash plugin**,  DVD playback, LAME (to create compressed audio files)
>   and patent codecs for  Chromium.

Answer (score -2):

Chromium doesn't have Flash with the browser. Chrome does.

Comment: Chrome include Google's wrapper around the flash plugin called PepperFlash. Chromium doesn't ship with it and use only the plugin from Adobe.