# How to play Farmville 2 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: flash, adobe

I have Mozilla 32 with this plugins installed:

> ```
> Shockwave Flash
>
>     Fájl: libflashplayer.so
>     Útvonal: /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
>     Verzió: 11.2.202.406
>     Állapot: Engedélyezve
>     Shockwave Flash 11.2 r202
>
> MIME-típus    Leírás  Kiterjesztés
> application/x-shockwave-flash Shockwave Flash swf
> application/futuresplash  FutureSplash Player spl
> Gnome Shell Integration
>
>     Fájl: libgnome-shell-browser-plugin.so
>     Útvonal: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libgnome-shell-browser-plugin.so
>     Verzió: 
>     Állapot: Engedélyezve
>     This plugin provides integration with Gnome Shell for live extension enabling and disabling. It can be used only by
> ```
>
> extensions.gnome.org
>
> ```
> MIME-típus    Leírás  Kiterjesztés
> application/x-gnome-shell-integration Gnome Shell Integration Dummy Content-Type  
> iTunes Application Detector
>
>     Fájl: librhythmbox-itms-detection-plugin.so
>     Útvonal: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/librhythmbox-itms-detection-plugin.so
>     Verzió: 
>     Állapot: Engedélyezve
>     This plug-in detects the presence of iTunes when opening iTunes Store URLs in a web page with Firefox.
>
> MIME-típus    Leírás  Kiterjesztés
> application/itunes-plugin     
> IcedTea-Web Plugin (using IcedTea-Web 1.5 (1.5-1ubuntu1))
>
>     Fájl: IcedTeaPlugin.so
>     Útvonal: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
>     Verzió: 
>     Állapot: Engedélyezve
>     The IcedTea-Web Plugin executes Java applets.
>
> MIME-típus    Leírás  Kiterjesztés
> application/x-java-vm IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.1 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.2 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.2   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.3 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.4 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.5 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.6 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;version=1.7 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.7.0_50    IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.1   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.1 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.2 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.1.3 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.2   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.1 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.2.2 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.3   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.3.1 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.4   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.1 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.4.2 IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.5   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.6   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;version=1.7   IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-bean;jpi-version=1.7.0_50  IcedTea class,jar
> application/x-java-vm-npruntime   IcedTea 
> DivX® Web Player
>
>     Fájl: libtotem-mully-plugin.so
>     Útvonal: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libtotem-mully-plugin.so
>     Verzió: 
>     Állapot: Engedélyezve
>     DivX Web Player version 1.4.0.233
>
> MIME-típus    Leírás  Kiterjesztés
> video/divx    AVI-videó   divx
> VLC Multimedia Plugin (compatible Videos 3.10.1)
>
>     Fájl: libtotem-cone-plugin.so
>     Útvonal: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libtotem-cone-plugin.so
>     Verzió: 
>     Állapot: Engedélyezve
>     The Videos 3.10.1 plugin handles video and audio streams.
>
> MIME-típus    Leírás  Kiterjesztés
> application/x-vlc-plugin  VLC Multimedia Plugin   
> application/vlc   VLC Multimedia Plugin   
> video/x-google-vlc-plugin VLC Multimedia Plugin   
> application/x-ogg Ogg multimédiafájl  ogg
> application/ogg   Ogg multimédiafájl  ogg
> audio/ogg Ogg hang    oga
> audio/x-ogg   Ogg hang    ogg
> audio/x-vorbis+ogg    Ogg Vorbis hang ogg
> video/ogg Ogg videó   ogv
> video/x-ogg   Ogg videó   ogg
> video/x-theora+ogg    Ogg Theora videó    ogg
> application/annodex   Annodex csereformátum   anx
> audio/annodex Annodex hang    axa
> video/annodex Annodex videó   axv
> video/mpeg    MPEG-videó  mpg, mpeg, mpe
> audio/wav WAV hang    wav
> audio/x-wav   WAV hang    wav
> audio/mpeg    MP3 hang    mp3
> application/x-nsv-vp3-mp3 NullSoft videó  nsv
> video/flv Flash videó flv
> video/webm    WebM videó  webm
> application/x-totem-plugin    Videos multimedia plugin    
> audio/midi    MIDI hang   mid, midi
> QuickTime Plug-in 7.6.6
>
>     Fájl: libtotem-narrowspace-plugin.so
>     Útvonal: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libtotem-narrowspace-plugin.so
>     Verzió: 
>     Állapot: Engedélyezve
>     The Videos 3.10.1 plugin handles video and audio streams.
>
> MIME-típus    Leírás  Kiterjesztés
> video/quicktime   QuickTime videó mov
> video/mp4 MPEG-4 videó    mp4
> image/x-macpaint  MacPaint bitkép pntg
> image/x-quicktime Macintosh Quickdraw/PICT-rajz   pict, pict1, pict2
> video/x-m4v   MPEG-4 videó    m4v
> application/vnd.apple.mpegurl HTTP élő lejátszólista  m3u8
> Windows Media Player Plug-in 10 (compatible; Videos)
>
>     Fájl: libtotem-gmp-plugin.so
>     Útvonal: /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libtotem-gmp-plugin.so
>     Verzió: 
>     Állapot: Engedélyezve
>     The Videos 3.10.1 plugin handles video and audio streams.
>
> MIME-típus    Leírás  Kiterjesztés
> application/x-mplayer2    AVI-videó   avi, wma, wmv
> video/x-ms-asf-plugin ASF videó   asf, wmv
> video/x-msvideo   AVI-videó   asf, wmv
> video/x-ms-asf    ASF videó   asf
> video/x-ms-wmv    Windows Media videó wmv
> video/x-wmv   Windows Media videó wmv
> video/x-ms-wvx    Windows Media videó wmv
> video/x-ms-wm Windows Media videó wmv
> video/x-ms-wmp    Windows Media videó wmv
> application/x-ms-wms  Windows Media videó wms
> application/x-ms-wmp  Windows Media videó wmp
> application/asx   Microsoft ASX lejátszólista asx
> audio/x-ms-wma    Windows Media hang  wma
> ```

These are the [official](https://www.zyngaplayersupport.com/article/farmville-2/Recommended-FarmVille-2-System-Requirements-en_US-1370046865691) requirements:

> Browser Version:
>
> Windows
>
> ```
> Google Chrome v.23 or higher
> Mozilla Firefox v.15 or higher
> ```
>
> Macintosh
>
> ```
> Google Chrome v.21 or higher
> Mozilla Firefox v.15 or higher
> Safari v.4 or higher
> ```
>
> To check your current browser version or to upgrade:
>
> 1. Open your browser
> 2. Click on the name of your browser from the top tool bar
> 3. Select About
>
> Flash Version
>
> ```
> Adobe Flash Player v.10.2 and up
> ```
>
> Java Version
>
> ```
> JAVA SE 6 and up
> ```

Note on [adobe](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/):

> NOTE: Adobe Flash Player 11.2 will be the last version to target Linux
>   as a supported platform. Adobe will continue to provide security
>   backports to Flash Player 11.2 for Linux.

If it works on MAC why not on Ubuntu? Maybe some workaround for this (modify request header or so...)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use Flash in Chromium](http://askubuntu.com/questions/311175/cannot-use-flash-in-chromium)

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED.**

Thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/395143/328276) post by Kenn.

See Pipelight with Firefox : http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @muru SO link provides that essencial info `-.-"`

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. But it's Stack Exchange policy that link-only answers are bad. Never mind, anyway I edited in the details in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/395143/158442) and marked this as a duplicate. You can flag this as a dupe and help the process.