# Install pepper flash player for Chromium on an offline PC?

Tags: flash, chromium

Where can I get the offline installers for pepper flash player plugin for Chromium?

I have an offline PC and I need to install pepper on it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do this on another computer with Internet connection: [How do I make Chromium use Flash from Google Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158388/how-do-i-make-chromium-use-flash-from-google-chrome)

Summary:

- PC Internet: install Google Chrome
- PC Internet: Copy the file to an USB stick
- PC NoInternet: Copy the file from the USB stick to: `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/` You need root rights for this (you could use `sudo nautilus` to open a root file manager)
- PC NoInternet: Change Chromium options, as described in the link.

Good luck.