# Pepper flash plugin is installed but doesn't work on chromium

Tags: 14.04, apt, flash, chromium

I have **Pepper Flash Plugin** installed, but it doesn't work on chromium and still every webpage prompts to install Adobe flash.

I removed and installed it again but nothing changed.
I'm sure it's installed because with attempt to new install get this message:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
pepperflashplugin-nonfree is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

**Ps.** This is how I removed the plugin before installing it again:

```
apt-get remove --purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  pepperflashplugin-nonfree*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
After this operation, 66.6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 199594 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.3ubuntu1) ...
Purging configuration files for pepperflashplugin-nonfree (1.3ubuntu1) ...

apt-get clean
```

Thanks

Comment: With what command did you remove it with the use of?

Comment: @Toroidal `sudo apt-get remove --purge pepperflashplugin-nonfree` then `sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: And what was the output of that command?

Comment: you can save your tendons some by typing `sudo apt-get purge` instead of `sudo apt-get remove --purge`

Comment: did you enable the plugin in your chromium settings?

Comment: So it's it only removing 1 package, and not all 6 that were installed. If you can get a list of those packages from the logs maybe from the Software Center then you can uninstall them manually.

Comment: @mchid Good to know about tendons, Thanks :) I just entered `chromium-browser --enable-plugins` now and got this: `/etc/chromium-browser/default: line 6: ./usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Toroidal Thank you. I'm not expert enough and don't have any idea about where the logs are located or how to trace them.

Comment: You should try running the command `sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: @Toroidal the output of `sudo apt-get autoremove` was `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.` Nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what was said on [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Flash) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/449266/25831) to simply install flash on Chromium by `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` package; I was forced to manually copy the pepperflash plugin file from Google chrome to chromium in the way expounded [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/216476/25831) :

---

> Download Google Chrome and extract `libpepflashplayer.so` from
>   `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash` in the Chrome deb file Copy
>   `libpepflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins` Make the
>   necessary changes to the Chromium startup
>
> ```
> sudo gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default
> ```
>
> Add this to the `CHROMIUM_FLAGS`
>
> ```
> CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=11.5.31.2"
> ```
>
> You can get the correct version of the flash plugin from the
>   `"version":` json tag in the `mainfest.json` from
>   `/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash` in the Chrome deb file

---

Now I have Adobe Flash Player - Version: 16.0.0.291 on Chromium and it works fine.
I don't know if I could get updates for flash on Chromium using this on Trminal:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --status
```

Because it doesn't give anything on Terminal.

**If you have any idea of how to keep the flash player updated on Chromium (without manually copying `.so` file eachtime a new version is released);**

**Also about the reason of `pepperflashplugin-nonfree` didn't copy the plugin file in Chromium folder or didn't update `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=""` in `/etc/chromium-browser/default` automtically, please let me know in comments.**

Thanks

Comment: This is just an idea how to deal with the update problem: instead of **copying** the plugin files to the chromium location, create a **symbolic link** to the file.

Comment: @BogdanWilli  Hmm, interesting. I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: @BogdanWilli Symlink has worked great. But one thing: this way the flash plugin version number in front  of`CHROMIUM_FLAGS` in the `/etc/chromium-browser/default`  would remain the old number and wouldn't change. So even though the file itself has been updated, but it presents a wrong version number to chromium (it can be seen  in `chrome://plugins`). I don't know if this affects the functionality of the plugin. However, if you have a solution for this too, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Also `sudo apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin` if you still have it installed because it will conflicts with pepperflashplugin-nonfree.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding version updates, you can add to /etc/chromium-browser/default the following line:

`version=$(grep version /opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/manifest.json | sed 's|.*"version": ||;s|"||g;s|,||')`

and change the the pappi-flash-version flag linke accordingly:

`CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/ --ppapi-flash-version=$version"`

**And put the actual path to the files**, wherever they are without having google chrome as well. Theoretically you don't even need any symlinks, unless the internal program rejects non-standard locations for some crazy reason, which would even lead anyone to question why it's asking for a location that should be hardcoded to begin with.

However, while it seems to work through chrome://plugins, on actual pages I get "couldn't load plugin". I don't think it's caused by this method of setting up the variables, though. Unless there are indeed crazy reasons.

Funnily enough chrome's flash works on chrome and firefox... but not chromium...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks your manual install fixed my problem. It shouldn't be too hard to script this.

I'm running Chromium Version 37.0.2062.120 on a Debian 7.1 fork.

I have a somewhat different problem. If I install pepperflash, apt-get removes chromium & chromium-browser:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chromium chromium-browser
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pepperflashplugin-nonfree
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 2 to remove
```

The opposite is also true, when installing chromium, apt-get will remove pepperflash if it's installed.

Here's what I did:

1. install `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`. This installed flash version 16.0.0.305.
2. copy the `/usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree` dir for use later.
3. install chromium and chromium-browser which removed `pepperflashplugin-nonfree`.
4. copy `libpepflashplayer.so` & `manifest.json` from the backup in step 2 to `/usr/lib/chromium/plugins` (I don't have a `/usr/lib/chromium-browser` dir).
5. edit `/etc/chromium/default` and append `--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=16.0.0.305 to CHROMIUM_FLAGS` (I don't have `/etc/chromium-browser/default`).

for example:

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--password-store=detect --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=16.0.0.305"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update, I used the method as described by DummyBeginner on a version of FLASH 23,0,0,185.

However I got the Pepper Lib directly from Adobe https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/?no_redirect

Downloaded the .tar.gz for my linux version, inside I found libpepflashplayer.so, copied that to the "plugins" directory of Chromium and updated the "default" file with the version I found in the manifesto.json.

Works like a charm on chromuim version 50.0.2661.102 and Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)