# Having tried differen ways but none worked - How do I disable a service from auto-start at boot in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, server, boot, configuration, services

This really doesn't make sense. I've been using many other distros and never had such difficulty managing autostart services.

I found three ways of disabling autostart services, and none of them works for me:

```
update-rc.d -f service_name remove
```

```
chkconfig --level 12345 service_name off
```

```
sysv-rc-conf
```

I tried all the three ways to disable mysql daemon, mongo daemon, redis server, cups daemon, yet all of the utilities confirmed that the daemons are disabled, yet they still automatically start on boot.

Please suggest the most correct way to disable services from auto-start at boot. Thank you!

btw, it's running 12.04

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable or disable services?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu has been moving away from sysv-init to Upstart. Some scripts won't work with: (as they have been moved to the Upstart format)

```
update-rc.d -f service_name remove
```

```
chkconfig --level 12345 service_name off
```

```
sysv-rc-conf
```

This has been answered in other posts, best answer I've seen so far is: (if you want more documentation on it)

https://askubuntu.com/a/19324/23779

So in a brief comment:

The current situation is: Ubuntu now uses Upstart. Some services still use the old sysv-init, are located in `/etc/init.d/` while other services, Upstart optimized are in `/etc/init/`. How to disable, stop, start, etc is explained in the above link.

Comment: that helps a lot, thank you. apparently /etc/init/SERVICE.override file does not have effect, but I'm able to disable mysql/mongodb/redis by using their own .override file. However I'm still unable to find a way to disable ntpd and dnsmasq... any further suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Bum is good startup manager suggested by many Ubuntu Users . open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

and to Launch the Bum , type this in your terminal .

```
gksu bum
```

Hope that helps .

Comment: thanks, I'm sure it'll help once I have a window manager installed C: