# name of a program for configure startup services

Tags: services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the recommended way to enable / disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services)

I forgot it, That program is in ubuntu official repositories

From my memory... That program have a `[ ]` box for tick `#` before each services.

It is not chkconfig, sysv-rc-conf, Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of `dselect`?

Comment: `tasksel`? (5 more chars needed)

Comment: nope, both dselect and tasksel are not use to configure startup services?

Comment: Not many left: [rcconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/rcconf.8.html)? It should be listed here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services

Comment: Yes, It is rcconf so you can use answer for me to toggle accepted answer..

Comment: @Smile: well, it's pretty much a duplicate question then, don't you think? I vote for close to keep the site tidy.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is `jobs-admin` : A service administration and configuration UI.

**Install:**  `sudo apt-get install jobs-admin`

**Execute:** `sudo jobs-admin`

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it is already listed in http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) ?

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't.