# How to add a program as a startup application from a terminal?

Tags: command-line, startup-applications

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I know the GUI way to maintain the startup program list but now I want to find out the way to add/remove startup applications using a command line interface (CLI).

Comment: Refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services?lq=1 and also possible duplicate

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/q/598195/72216

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your home directory, there's a folder called **.config/autostart**. Anything placed in this folder will be run when you login. This could be accomplished through the command line by creating the **.desktop** file with the command `nano ~/.config/autostart/blah.desktop`. If you like to find out about the syntax of **.desktop** files, you can visit [Freedesktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and [Gnome](http://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en).

Comment: What to put in the file:
`[Desktop Entry]
 Type=Application
 Exec=/full/link/to/your/newshell.sh (OR sh -c 'your command')
 Name=newshell
 Comment=whatever you want`
Note: Change Exec, Name and Comment values.