# Modify keyboard layout Unity in 14.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, 14.04, xkb

How to set the Meta key with xkb? Adding

```
key <AA06> {    [ meta,         meta    ]    };
```

to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` (in the "basic" section) and then running `sudo dpgk-reconfigure xkb-data` seems to work some times, and other times not. In particular, it seems to forget my setting when I switch back and forth between keyboard layouts (even though I added a similar line to the Swedish layout that I'm also using).

Checking with `xev`, the key I want as meta is initially mapped to `Meta_L` (as it should be) but after a switch of keyboard layouts, it's mapped to `NoSymbol`. Sometimes the behaviour is less predictable, and it's mapped to 'NoSymbol' already at boot.

How would I go ahead to get a better picture of where it's going wrong?

Comment: Try modifying `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the place to edit control keys. Behaviour is similar to before though (possibly because I'm just guessing at the syntax).

At the moment the Meta key seems to be set this way
`   key <META> { [ NoSymbol, Meta_L ] };
    modifier_map Mod1   { <META> };`

I tried to change that to `key <META> { [Meta_L] };` but no noticeable effects.

Comment: Thanks, that I already run every time. Sorry for not mentioning it. Added it to the question now.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any extended keyboard to try, see with `key <AA06> { [ NoSymbol, Meta_L ] };
    modifier_map Mod1   { <AA06> };`

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Thanks for your help. I think I can live without the meta key, it's not too important. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the existing compiled keybindings?

```
sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm
```

Then, restart.

Credit: [Why did 13.10 break my custom keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361128/why-did-13-10-break-my-custom-keyboard-layout/361584#361584)