# us keyboard not working in 14.04 after removing *.xkm files from /var/lib/xkb

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xkb

I wanted to customize my keyboard shortcuts and followed the advice given here:
[Why did 13.10 break my custom keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361128/why-did-13-10-break-my-custom-keyboard-layout/361584)

I modified my `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file and deleted `*.xkm` files from `/var/lib/xkb` and rebooted. But for some reason Ubuntu failed to recompile the `*.xkm` files and now my `us` keyboard isn't working. (Even us virtual screen keyboard on Ubuntu login screen doesn't work due to missing xkm errors). For some strange reason my Russian keyboard layout still works, but it doesn't help much. So how can I restore those `*xkm` files in `/var/lib/xkb`? I have `*xkm` files in another computer, maybe I can just copy them to the broken one?

This command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data` didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that problem was with the `/var/lib/xkb` folder write permissions. I changed it with:

```
sudo chmod a=rwx /var/lib/xkb
```

(which was not easy without english/us keyboard) And after reboot I was able to use US layout again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, would you accept your own answer as this what worked for you.