# how do I remove a startup application from the command line?

Tags: xubuntu

In Xubuntu, how do I remove a startup application that was set in `Menu –> Setting –> Settings Manager –> Sessions and Startup` without using the GUI? My startup command breaks the gui, and I need to disable it using the command line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a program as startup application from terminal ?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178567/how-to-add-a-program-as-startup-application-from-terminal)

Answer (score 29):

Quoting the Xfce Docs ("[Some of my applications are always started when I login](http://wiki.xfce.org/faq#some_of_my_applications_are_always_started_when_i_login)"):

> You can also manually delete those files in ~/Desktop/Autostart and ~/.config/autostart.

For example: open a terminal, type

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
ls
```

then `rm` the files that you want to delete.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04,  ~/.config/autostart is the directory

Answer (score 1):

You can disable autostart entries by hiding them with a higher-precedence entry.

If you don't have it yet, create your own `autostart` folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
```

and then create `.desktop` files matching the names of the ones you want to disable from `/etc/xdg/autostart` (or other sources such as `/usr/share/gnome/autostart`).

For example, disabling print-applet:

```
cat > ~/.config/autostart/print-applet.desktop <<EOF
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Hidden=true
EOF
```

Comment: While this is likely a bug in the way current gnome-session and gio interact, the hiding desktop file will be ignored if it doesn't contain a Type=Application key-value pair as well.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be surprised if some desktops fail to hide the entry if not providing a Name key as well.