# How do I totally disable all forms of session management in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

Xubuntu remembers things like `xfce-terminal` and `chromium` whenever my system starts up. I don't want that function to happen, ever. I want every restart to be fresh. How do I disable this functionality. I've seen numerous tutorials that unchecking the *"Save sessions for future logins"* screen in Log Off would work, but it does't seem to work for me. When the system comes back the other applications are open.

I've also deleted the files in `autostart`, as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/315555/29097).

Answer (score 7):

Launch `xfce4-settings-editor`, find and uncheck *xfce4-session* -> *general* -> *SaveOnExit*.

Answer (score 3):

**Hope this would help you somewhat**

The method I'm telling would not be the best but it would work for you. This will enable the way to start with a new session every time you login. You can also login with default session.

Just follow these steps.

- Open **Session and Startup** from **Menu** - > **Settings** -> **Settings Manager**.
- `Untick` the `Automatically save sessions on logout` under **Logout Settings**
- <kbd>Close</kbd> the Session and Startup window.
- Logout or restart your system to be sure if you got what you desired.

**Another way**

If above doesn't work for you then you can start a session every time you login by:

- Again in **Session and Startup** Window just `tick` the option `Display chooser in login` under **Session Chooser**
- Logout and login with a different session by giving a name.

That's all.

Reply if you need further assistance.

Comment: I think I found a bug. Although the checkboxes are empty, opening the xfce4-settings-editor I saw internally was still CHECKED !!! SaveOnExit

Answer (score 0):

It seems XFCE Sessions occasionally get stuck even if you uncheck *Automatically save session on logout*.

This may happen after you have it checked (and a session is saved) and you uncheck it. Somehow the last saved session is perpetually restored.

To solve this, after unchecking ***Automatically save session on logout*** in *Settings Manager* > *Session and Startup* > *Saved sessions* delete all saved sessions.

This should take care of the stuck session.