# Ubuntu Server is resetting folder permissions for .ssh on reboot

Tags: permissions, ssh, reboot

Every time I power cycle the machine the .ssh folder permissions are reset and become too open for ssh.

I need to physically go to the machine and

```
chmod 0700 ~/.ssh
```

before I can ssh in (otherwise I get a permission denied (publickey) error) What would do that on boot up and how can I prevent it?

The machine is going to be deployed in a location that is not easily accessible to me, so I can't have it setup in a way that requires me to be there every time it is rebooted.

In case this is useful information. The machine is a fairly basic setup, Ubuntu Server 14.04 with nginx, php-fpm, mysql server, git, openssh. It has an SSD and 2 HDDs setup with RAID1.

Other than installing the OS & software, the only things I've done to the machine are: add a site to nginx, setup a database in mysql, and copy the public keys (from the 3 machines that will have access) into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

The only none vanilla/standard things on there are: I mounted the RAID "drive" to /vol/ moved the mysql folder to /vol/mysql/ and cloned the webapp from github to /vol/www/

Answer (score 0):

You can make this command to execute every time you boot your system using the **'Startup Applications'** that is available by default in ubuntu.

Just type 'Startup Applications' in the dash board. An application will open. Click **Add** button in the application and type the command (In your case, its *chmod 0700 ~/.ssh*) and u can also specify the Name and Comment for that command.

Now, every time you boot your system, this command gets executed automatically. You can also take a look on adding the startup programs on command line [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178567/how-to-add-a-program-as-startup-application-from-terminal)

Comment: It's a headless server, but yes, I was thinking of adding the command to crontab or whatever the statup bash script is as a workaround. It just seems like an odd behavior and I'd like to know why it is happening.

Comment: In ubuntu, certain things like this gets reseted every time you reboot and this is not an odd behavior. You can add the command as I said or add your command in /etc/rc.local.

Comment: Sorry @harirehm this is absolutely a strange behavior and should not be happening.