# How to add a script to Startup Applications from the command line?

Tags: autostart, startup-applications

I have a shell script. I want to configure my script to run automatically during startup. I know how to do this from GUI. But I wanted to do this from terminal. How can I do this?

On a primary research I found that the file needs to be moved to `/etc/int.d/` directory. But this operation needs sudo permission. **I wanted to do this without super user permissions.**

I also found that there are files under `~/.config/autostart/` which are having some settings regarding the startup applications. But I don't know how to edit them to achieve this.

Can someone tell me the exact procedure to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to have it run on *user level* or globally? Also: you could create a launcher in `~/.config/autostart` from command line, but it would take... a minor script :). Would that be ok?

Comment: User level shall do. I am also trying to write a script. But unaware of the files which are needed to be edited. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### How to set up a startup launcher from command line

Like you mention in your question, commands can be run on log in by placing a launcher in `~/.config/autostart` Since the launcher is only used to startup a script, you only need the "basic" desktop entry keywords in the created `.desktop` files: the keywords / lines you'd need at least:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=name
Exec=command
Type=Application
```

The (optional) line `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` will be added automatically if you enable/disable the autostart function of the launcher (it is set to `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` by default)

More on required fields, you can find [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).

#### Example script

To create such a launcher from the command line, you would need a small script that would take the name of the starter and the command to run as an argument. An example of such a script below.

If I run it with the command:

```
python3 '/path/to/script' 'Test' 'gedit'
```

It creates a startup launcher, running `gedit` when I login. 
The launcher is also visible in Dash > Startup Applications:

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
home = os.environ["HOME"]

name = sys.argv[1]; command = sys.argv[2]

launcher = ["[Desktop Entry]", "Name=", "Exec=", "Type=Application", "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true"]
dr = home+"/.config/autostart/"
if not os.path.exists(dr):
    os.makedirs(dr)
file = dr+name.lower()+".desktop"

if not os.path.exists(file):
    with open(file, "wt") as out:     
        for l in launcher:
            l = l+name if l == "Name=" else l
            l = l+command if l == "Exec=" else l
            out.write(l+"\n")
else:
    print("file exists, choose another name")
```

Paste it into an empty file, save it as `set_startupscript.py`, run it by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/set_startupscript.py '<name>' '<command>'
```

#### What it does

- It creates a basic launcher (you don't need more, running a script) in `~/.config/autostart`, taking the name and command as arguments.
- If a launcher with the name already exists in `~/.config/autostart`, it prints a message:

  ```
  file exists, choose another name
  ```

Comment: @AnonymousPlatypus aaarrgh, forgot the `import sys` line. fixed.

Comment: @Jacob What should you put in the place of <name> and <command>?

Comment: @DevRobot `<name>` is the name of your *Startup Application*, as it appears in the list of Dash > Startup Applications. You can give it any name you like. The `<command>` is the command you'd like to run. If it is simply a bash script, use: `'/bin/bash /path/to/script.sh'`, (including quotes) if it is a complicated command, use `/bin/bash -c "<complicated_command>"`. What is the command you'd like to run on startup?

Comment: @Jacob, it's a bash script containing randr settings

Comment: @DevRobot then the first option will do (don't forget the quotes :) )

Comment: @Jacob Last question ;) I'm using python to write the above python script into a file, but the `\n` in the code creates a new line in the file, it isn't copied as `\n`, so I get an EOL error. How can I solve this?

Comment: @DevRobot You mean integrate it in an existing script? Then I would fit it in a function. For easy maintenance you could keep it as a separate module and either import it, or call it by `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()`. Is it `python2` or `3`? For more to the point looking into it, probably better to post a question.

Comment: The script is very handy - it's going in my toolbox. :-)

Answer (score 13):

I found an answer

cd to `~/.config/autostart/`. If you don'y have a folder named **autostart** then create one with that name using mkdir autostart.

Now add the following file with the name `yourScript.sh.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec="/Your/location/to/theScript/yourScript.sh"
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_IN]=AnyNameYouWish
Name=AnyNameYouWish
Comment[en_IN]=AnyComment
Comment=AnyComment
```

Done!

Comment: To run a script on startup, there are more fields here than needed :)

Comment: Could you please tell me about the additional fields?

Comment: only a few of these fields are really required, if you look at this site: http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html in column `REQ`, you can see if you really need the keyword. I would only use additional keywords if you have a reason to. `Nodisplay`, `Hidden`, `Comment` etc. play no role when you don't run launchers from Dash.

Comment: I have checked the file. As you said, according to that only `Type`,`EXEC` and `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled` tags would be required. Thanks for pointing this out. :)

Comment: Wait, `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled` ? That is not needed, and is not even mentioned on the linked page.

Comment: I believe the X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled key tell it to actually start the program, if it were set to false then it would appear disabled in the list of startup programs.

Comment: You are right! If the line is not in the `.desktop file`, the default value is `true`, if you disable it from Dash > Startup Applications, the line is added automatically. I edited it into the script.