# New line in python script creating EOL error

Tags: python, development, debugging

I'm creating a Python program for Ubuntu, and I need to write a python script into a file, but the `\n` in the code creates a new line in the file, it isn't copied as `\n`, so I get an EOL error.

This is the code for the Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
home = os.environ["HOME"]

name = sys.argv[1]; command = sys.argv[2]

launcher = ["[Desktop Entry]", "Name=resolutionx", "Exec=/bin/bash resolutionx.sh", "Type=Application", "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true"]
file = home+"/.config/autostart/"+name.lower()+".desktop"

if not os.path.exists(file):
    with open(file, "wt") as out:     
        for l in launcher:
            l = l+name if l == "Name=resolutionx" else l
            l = l+command if l == "Exec=/bin/bash resolutionx.sh" else l
            out.write(l+"\n")
else:
  print("file exists, choose another name")
```

In this part:

```py
if not os.path.exists(file):
    with open(file, "wt") as out:     
        for l in launcher:
            l = l+name if l == "Name=resolutionx" else l
            l = l+command if l == "Exec=/bin/bash resolutionx.sh" else l
            out.write(l+"\n")
```

The code for writing the above to the file is:

```
fStartUpScript = open("set_startupscript.py", "w")
fStartUpScript.write("""
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
home = os.environ["HOME"]

name = sys.argv[1]; command = sys.argv[2]

launcher = ["[Desktop Entry]", "Name=resolutionx", "Exec=/bin/bash resolutionx.sh", "Type=Application", "X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true"]
file = home+"/.config/autostart/"+name.lower()+".desktop"

if not os.path.exists(file):
    with open(file, "wt") as out:     
        for l in launcher:
            l = l+name if l == "Name=resolutionx" else l
            l = l+command if l == "Exec=/bin/bash resolutionx.sh"     else l
            out.write(l+"\\n")
else:
  print("file exists, choose another name")""")
fStartUpScript.close()
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking..could you please provide an example..

Comment: Ah here you are :) You should probably post the code and the script you want to integrate :)

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu, you should instead ask in in SO http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Maythux it is very much related to Ubuntu, but the question needs some additional information.

Comment: @JacobVlijm How is it related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Better to ask this on StackOverfllow.

Comment: @Maythux the question is about a script on adding applications to Startup Applications, and integrating it into another script somehow. The essential information is currently missing however :). The question is the result of a comment on another question / answer. see http://askubuntu.com/a/598202/72216

Comment: `The essential information is currently missing however. ` I have nothing to say more, so I can't say it's related to Ubuntu yet

Comment: @Maythux Fair enough, let's see what happens :)

Comment: Probably you just have to escape the backslash, so that it will be printed as backslash+"n" instead of being interpreted as newline character: `\\n`

Comment: Done :) @Byte Commander Post an answer, so I can give you credit

Comment: @JacobVlijm No. someone edited my question and put that. I want to write the above script into a file using python, but when I write it to the file, the `\n` is not written, but actually creates a new line.

Comment: I;ve edited the Q again to show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Understanding what the script should do

I am afraid you are misunderstanding how the script should be applied. There is no reason to have another script *write* this script into a file whatsoever.

That would be the same as writing an application to write an application; a huge detour, and a strange thing to do. you should simply *create* the script:

1. Copy / paste the script from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/598202/72216) into an empty file, save it as `set_startupscript.py`
2. *Call* it with the right arguments:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_startupscript.py '<name>''<command>'
   ```

   where:

   ```
    '<name>'
   ```

   is the name of the launcher to be produced, between quotes, and

   ```
   '<command>'
   ```

   is the command to be run by the launcher, also between quotes.

Then it creates a launcher in `~/.config/autostart`, which will run the command: `'<command>'` on log in.

The script itself is not to be used as a startup script, but to *create* a launcher in `~/.config/autostart` to run a command.

#### Copy the script

*IF* you would need to copy the script for some reason (but again: *why*), or you need to copy any other file to another location, in `python3`, use:

```
shutil.copyfile(sourcefile, target)
```

Comment: Lol :D It's **not** for me. It's part of a program that will create the said script onto a user's PC

Comment: ooooohhhhhh I understand :-D

Comment: I get this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/devrobot/.config/autostart/resolutionx.desktop'
`

Comment: `python3 set_startupscript.py 'resolutionx' '/bin/bash resolutionx.sh'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25203/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-devrobot).

Comment: @DevRobot You probably never created a Startup Application before,  so the directory `~/.config/autostart` didn't exist yet. Didn't count on that one in the script. fixed it here: http://askubuntu.com/a/598202/72216 please copy the latest version :) Nice catch!

Comment: I can't seem to log in for seem reason. btw the command returns nothing