# Have xrandr -o left run on startup

Tags: display, upstart, xrandr, orientation

I know very little about Ubuntu. Enough to make my own persistent instance of the OS on a flashdrive I keep with me, and enough to navigate and move/copy/delete/make directories/install/update, but I have absolutely NO clue how to even begin with using Upstart.

I have a PC at work that runs Ubuntu 16.04, it's connected to a display that's oriented in portrait, but the only way to properly format the content it's running is to run `sudo xrandr -o left` every single morning. This is obviously not ideal.

I can follow directions *very* well, but I would be so so so thrilled if someone could walk me through how to handle something like this from the beginning. As it stands, I have Upstart installed on that PC and a test PC I can use to try things on until I get back to that work space early next week.

Thank you guys so much for your time!

Comment: [How to add a script to Startup Applications from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/598202/507051) will help you – a `.desktop` file with `Exec=xrandr -o left` should do the trick. Why did you use `sudo` for that?

Comment: @dessert  I've been doing it as a `sudo` because the OS of the system is modified quite a bit to fit the role it's being used for. It's not a standard desktop, and roughly half the time if I don't do it as `sudo` then sometimes it will lose the display in the middle of the switch and not change at all, as if it's being reconnected in the middle. I'll give this a shot. Thank you so much!

Comment: If it needs `sudo` you can use `kdesudo` or `gksudo` respectively, they will ask for your password.

Comment: @dessert Starting `xrandr` in `/etc/rc.local` will FAIL every time - `xrandr` needs a running X server, which hasn't been started at the time `/etc/rc.local` is executed. Context!

Comment: You can explore [Xrandr Official Documentation](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution). There must be a way to set this config directly in .cfg xrandr files, with no need to build a workaround to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/637911/301745)