# Stop KDE services from running

Tags: kde, services, kde4

I recently installed KDE with the command `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`.

Now whenever I log into Unity I can see KDE-related services running in the background and I see no obvious way to prevent them from opening at startup. I checked `bum` but I see nothing there.

These are the services I see running right now:

`kde4`
`klauncher`
`knotify4`

These ones I can identify as being related to KDE given their names, but there could be more.

How can I prevent these services from launching by themselves?

I should mention I often use KDE applications such as `kate`, `okular` and `kile`. Could these be responsible for opening those services?

Comment: I have the same issue and I have uninstalled KDE so lets hope for an answer to this issue.  Because it seems to me the start-up process is never cleaned, or isn't cleaned well enough.

Answer (score 3):

You need to utilize "startup services" to disable those specific processes.

See this link for more information [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services)

It gives you some options as "how to".

Go to System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications. Un-check things which you want to disable on startup.

Comment: No, this is not correct. Only a few services are shown here and the ones presumably left over from the `KDE` install do not show (nor do many others not related to `KDE`; this app is in fact quite simplistic and borderline useless for any need semi-advanced)

Comment: Thank you for the link tough, it looks like it has some very useful info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, KDE applications such as the ones you mentioned do require kde related processes to run. Unfortunately there is no way to stop these processes from running

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f insertnameofservice remove
```

See also [How-To: Managing services with update-rc.d](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-managing-services-with-update-rc-d/)

Comment: This looks like the right direction.  How do you see all of the services running or started?

Comment: Do you mean the services running right now? Alt+F2 and "gnome-system-monitor" or "htop" for the terminal list all running services.