# What service starts a user session before they login?

Tags: login, kde, upstart, dropbox, insync

I've noticed that I have problems with insync and dropbox icons showing up in my system tray and in investigating the problem it seems to be because they are being started before I even login.

In investigation I tried a fresh reboot and login to the command line. When I did a ps -ef | grep  I noticed that all of my session processes were being started before I even logged into the GUI. This includes KDE, insync, dropbox, etc. When I traced the PPID's of these processes it goes back to my entire KDE session being started by init (PID 1!)

The problems with insync, dropbox, etc. are solved if I kill all of these processes before I login.

Does anyone know what initscript or upstart job could be starting my user session before I've even logged in? (I'm on kubuntu 10.14)

Comment: Probably upstart. What processes are you asking about exactly ?

Comment: I know it's upstart b/c the parent process traces back to PID 1. However, what I'm wondering is what upstart configuration or perhaps 'service' is starting this session and how can I disable it? (Seems like something setup to minimize login times.)

Comment: could be preload, hard to know from what little you have told us. Again, what "service" or process are you asking about? Post the output of the exact command you ran `ps -ef|grep` does not tell us much. Yo could also have a bug or misconfiguration in insycn, dropbox, etc. You simply are not giving us sufficient information.

Comment: When the computer boots, before I login to KDM, if I instead login at the console I see many processes already running that would form my KDE session. I am wondering if there is some upstart configuration, script, etc. that would pre-load my actual KDE session before I've even logged into KDE. I'll post something more in terms of a list of the processes so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I don't have preload installed.

Comment: See the list of processes running (before I've even logged in) here: http://pastebin.com/t4xeFhKn

Comment: First, that is a huge output, some of those things are running because you logged into a console. Second, kde runs this way, it is normal. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/225822/stop-kde-services-from-running and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man8/kdeinit5.8.html

Comment: you will have to either be more specific , or search each process one-by-one (google) :) You really need to revise your question with a description of the problem and why you think any or all of these processes are related to dropbox, etc

Comment: KDE does not run this way. It is very unusual to start user processes, let alone an entire user session before the user has logged in. kdeinit should start when your xsession starts. There are multiple user accounts on my computer and this does not happen for any other user account. I've been doing some troubleshooting and there is something in my local .config direction (not the autostart subdir) that is triggering this. Right now I suspect that some process is starting which is triggering an entire kde session to start, while disconnected from an X server. I'll post once I've isolated it.

Comment: Really? I am running Fedora and have KDE installed, but kde processes are running in the background een though I am logged into XFCE with KDE services disabled in the XFCE options. You might look closer at the man pages for kde, especailly kdeinit5.

Comment: Yes, really, because you are logged into X. If you want to check, right after you boot your computer and before you login to X, hit <Ctrl>+<alt>+F1 and login to the console. Then check your processes. ps -ef | grep <userid> You should not have any GUI/X related processes running. BTW: I found the culprit. chrome-remote-desktop. There is a service that init runs and checks all users of the group chrome-remote-desktop and will start a session on Xvfb for each user in that group if you have a config in ~/.config/chrome-remote-desktop. I've disabled it now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you would have to boot to recovery mode or disable your DM (GDM / KDM).