# How can I disable transmission-daemon autostart

Tags: autostart, transmission

I tried **rcconf** and **update-rc.d** but transmission-daemon starting each time i boot the system.

Comment: try `echo 'manual' | sudo tee /etc/init/transmission-daemon.override` (from http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services)