# Ubuntu LAMP server do I need the DNS Service?

Tags: server

I have a VPS which was setup preinstalled with various different services I want to know can I remove things like DNS,POP,IMAP etc without affecting my LAMP setup? Im pretty sure I don't need these...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a mail server, by all means disable it. From a security standpoint, the less number of services you run the less exposed you are to external attacks (fewer "attack vectors" in the industry parlance.)

Keep in mind that some times the service you are planning to provide depends on other services (for example it makes little sense to run an e-shop and not offer the means to communicate by e-mail with your users.)

It really all depends on what your use case is. Research the requirements of the s/w you plan to run and then make any necessary changes to the running services by means of Webmin (check out www.webmin.com for instructions) or if you prefer command line check out this thread [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/whats-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services)