# Why am I getting "Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address" when starting Apache2?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I can stop it using

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

But when I want to start it again using:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

I get this error:

```
Starting web server apache2                                                  /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Some words about the errors you get which hopefully will save you from similar situations in future.

In Linux ports from 0 to 1024 are reserved for system use. This means that in order to use one, you must have the authority to change - access basic system settings. The root user has such privileges and can actually use a port  from the range 0 - 1024.

In your problem as you can see, the system through Apache2 response indicates the root of the problem ([...]could not bind to address blah blah **80**):

```
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
```

When the Apache2 http daemon starts, it tries to bind the 80 port as it is the default port for use in HTTP [see](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)), which is a port within the system assigned ports and as such it can only be accessed by root.

You executed the start command as a typical user without root privileges and led to failure to do so.

**In simple words:**

You:

> Hi Apache2. I am Kongthap and I am telling you to start (`/etc/init.d/apache2 start`)

Apache2:

> OK. I am starting (Starting web server apache2)
>
> System, please give me port 80 to use and listen for connections.

System:

> OK. One moment to check...
>
> Ahh... Sorry Apache2 but I cannot let you run at 80 port, it is for personal use.
>
> And you do not have the correct privileges to bind it. (`Operation not permitted`)

Apache2:

> Ohh, Kongthap I failed to start, the System did not let me do it (`(13)Permission denied:[...]`)

**Conclusion**

There are mainly two solutions to this problem:

1. Run the Apache2 HTTP daemon with root privileges using `sudo`:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 start
   ```

   or:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
   ```
2. Change the default port from `80` to something greater than `1024`, say `2000`, `2500`, `9000`, etc. A typical port to run when in such situation is `8080`

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/apache2/ports.conf
   ```

   look for or if not there add:

   ```
   Listen 8080
   ```

   or any other port of your choice such as port `> 1024` and the selected port is **not** used by another process.

Comment: Really excellent explanation!!!

Comment: Great explanation, understood well!

Comment: Great explanation. Why is using `service` the preferred method?

Comment: They are Upstart directives, check this question and answers http://askubuntu.com/q/19320/12218 and for more detailed view check the upstart cookbook http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/. Keep in mind these refer to the services (daemon) handling (when and how to start-stop) this question and my answer also tackles the permission problems.

Comment: Needless wordiness. Answer does not address the problem.

Comment: @reggie that may be your opinion but the answer does solve the op's problem, in addition explains in extremely simple terms how one can avoid such situations. So if your problem is not solved by the answer, either your problem is not the same as the op's or you did not understand the explanation - solution provided here.

Comment: `sudo service apache2 start` does NOT run the service as root, it starts the service as root. By default systemd services run as root anyway - all sudo does is let you start/stop them. If your apache service is configured to run as apache it matters not that you start it with root.

Answer (score 7):

**Following are the commands to start/stop/restart apache server:**

- To start:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
  ```
- To stop:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
  ```
- To restart:

  ```
  sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
  ```

Comment: After restart the computer, it seems ok with all commands you suggested but I got this message during restarting...
Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

Comment: @Kongthap: that's not an error. I'm sure the web is full of explanation for that message.

Comment: Yes, @AndreaCorbellini is correct. It is not an error, it says because your ip does not have any Fully Qualified Domain Name for example mail.google.com.

Answer (score 5):

Check the selinux port context by issuing command

```
semanage port -l | grep http
```

If it's present in the http_port_t list then it's OK, otherwise add your port by

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 80
```

or something that you want to assign.

Comment: This was helpful, will add that issuing `semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8081` may fail if the port is already defined. What then helped me get past that was issuing a subsequent command `semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 8081`

Answer (score 1):

This is an selinux error, or at least it was in my case. Either change the boolean, disable selinux, or set it for permissive with `setenforce 0`.

The boolean change would require you to run `getenforce -a | grep http`, and look for the "allow http connect network". Copy it and replace "on" where the list says "-- off"

Comment: Ubuntu use AppArmor not SELinux, so your answer is irrelevant to ubuntu.

Comment: As a centos user who got this problem and this is the first stackoverflow question to come up I appreciate the help this fixed my issue