# Boot-up Manager seems like doesn't work

Tags: boot, 13.04

I installed Boot-up Manager, unchecked all services I don't want to load, but nonetheless they autostart each time and I have to stop them manually:

```
alex@lenovo:~$ sudo service mysql stop
mysql stop/waiting
alex@lenovo:~$ sudo service postgresql stop
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.2 database server                               [ OK ] 
alex@lenovo:~$ sudo service mongodb stop
mongodb stop/waiting
```

What's up with that?

Comment: did you get it all working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have done is asked a few services to stop ... and they have responded by telling you "ok we have stopped".

You have ONLY asked them to stop while they were running, you have not changed their configuration start-up mode.

Try this:

- [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services)