# Tool to disable services and daemons

Tags: software-recommendation, upstart, init, tools

For the old (and still used in debian) init mechanism there are tools such as `rcconf` to disable services and daemons.

Are there such for whatever is used in Ubuntu (upstart I guess) ?

I am running 12.04.3. (I know you can disable some by messing with the files in `/etc/init` directory, but I would prefer a tool like rcconf.)

It does not have to be graphical.

I know how to install and use `rcconf`, but Ubuntu uses a newer init mechanism, and I do not think `rcconf` works with that.

Services-admin apparently provided by `gnome-system-tools` seems good, although might have dependencies I want to avoid on my minimal install.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable or disable services?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, Ubuntu provides a graphical tool to manage services that start up at boot time.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo services-admin
```

Or you can install rcconf.

```
sudo apt-get install rcconf
```

and start it by typing `rcconf` in terminal

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Check also  :

1. [bum - boot-up menager](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bum.html)
2. [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)

HTH