# Celeryd not running at startup

Tags: init.d

I ran `sudo update-rc.d celeryd defaults`

All good.

I ran:

```
/etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

All good.

I restart machine.

All bad.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd status
```

celeryd not running (no pidfile)

I'm a noob on linux and I don't even have the first idea of where to look to find some error messages.  I checked `/var/log` but I don't see anything relevant.  `/var/log/celery` is empty.  But if I manually `run celeryd start`, then `/var/log/celery` will have some logs.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the process.

1. Put the `celeryd` file inside `/etc/init.d/`
2. Make it executable

   ```
   sudo chmod +x celeryd
   ```
3. Make it run on startup

   ```
   sudo update-rc.d celeryd defaults
   sudo update-rc.d celeryd enable <------- Are you currently missing this step?
   ```
4. Make it owned by root and have the correct permissions

   ```
   sudo chown root:root celeryd
   sudo chmod 777 celeryd
   ```

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 celeryd` 777 for an executable? Are you serious?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the system to auto start it. Read these [excellent answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-enable-disable-services/20351#20351) on the  different ways you can achieve this.