# Is there a central configuration tool for ubuntu such as yast on opensuse?

Tags: configuration, administration, tools

In openSUSE there is a set up tool called YaST working on GUI and command line. Is there such tool for Ubuntu for instance on YaST one can configure samba and the services.

Here is a picture for those that do not know:
[image: pic off of wikipedia]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Tweak does much of that - you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

It looks like this:

[image: Ubuntu Tweak]

As for Service Administration, this may work:

```
sudo apt-get install jobs-admin
```

[image: jobs-admin]

For more, see the question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/19320/178596).