# Multi-user text mode runlevel in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, server, upstart, debian, runlevel

I use Ubuntu as a server, and I want to change its runlevel to be full multi-user text mode (like init 3 in RedHat).

From this command `runlevel` i see that am running  `N 2` which is Graphical multi-user with networking based on this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel

So I'm wondering, is "1- Single-user mode" in Ubuntu the equivalent for "3- Full multi-user text mode" in RedHat?

Comment: To people passing by: time has passed and Ubuntu has switched to `systemd`, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/788323/change-runlevel-on-16-04 for an updated question and answer.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. Ubuntu uses [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) as its init daemon. Upstart does handle runlevels and legacy init-style scripts for backwards compatibility, but most boot processes installed by Ubuntu itself are Upstart jobs. Upstart jobs do not start and stop on numbered runlevels like traditional init scripts do.

However, on a Red Hat system, the primary difference between runlevel 3 (multi-user text mode) and runlevel 5 (graphical desktop login) is whether `gdm` is running. So to approximate Red Hat's runlevel 3 on Ubuntu, the `lightdm` login manager can be either uninstalled or disabled.

Uninstall `lightdm` with

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
```

or disable the `lightdm` upstart job following the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19324/70254).