# How can I stop YaCy from starting when my machine starts?

Tags: services, search, engine

I have installed the YaCy P2P search engine following these instructions (adding the YaCy repo to my sources and installing from there): http://www.yacy-websuche.de/wiki/index.php/En:DebianInstall

That page includes instructions on starting/stopping the YaCy daemon:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/yacy stop
sudo /etc/init.d/yacy start
sudo /etc/init.d/yacy restart
```

I can stop YaCy right now, but it starts again the next time I boot up. How can I stop it doing that, and only start when I tell it to (with `sudo /etc/init.d/yacy start`)?

This Upstart technique to permanently disable a service (accepted answer at [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)) does not work (YaCy still starts next time I boot):

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'manual' > /etc/init/yacy.override"
#doesn't work
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind unfortunately sudo sh -c "echo 'manual' > /etc/init/yacy.override" doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all the [general answers on disabling a service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services), this "traditional" technique is the one that works with YaCy (it is not an Upstart service, so that technique doesn't work):

```
sudo update-rc.d yacy disable
sudo service yacy stop
```

This will stop YaCy and prevent it from starting on the next bootup. You can start it again at any time by running:

```
sudo service yacy start
#or sudo /etc/init.d/yacy start as in the original instructions
```

If you prefer using a GUI, I saw that the yacy service did appear in BootUp Manager (I didn't test disabling from there, but since it's using a well-established control technique, I assume it will work). To install BootUp Manager:

```
sudo apt install bum
#then run it from the Dash
```