# How to enable Lubuntu lightdm dinamic autologin (sorry for my english)

Tags: lubuntu, login, lightdm

Hi I freshly installed Lubuntu 14.04

I disabled lightdm autostarting by editing /etc/default/grub

Well.. I got some problems

1. "sudo service lightdm start" is working but startx command always freezes at "Loading extensions GLX
2. When I turn on computer I have to login console
   and when I type "sudo service lightdm start" I have to input password again
   and finally when Lightdm is started I have to login again
   that's very bothering me

What I want to do is when I login into console it should be possible to login into Xwindows directly with currentuser who logined console
linuxubuntu gonny95 is online now       Report This Post

Comment: *How* did you disable LightDM by editing Grub's configuration?

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"

Comment: For starters I would suggest undoing that and just [overriding the `lightdm` service to make it manual](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services) without disturbing how the boot process works. This is pretty simple so update your post after you've done that.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution. Typing `rm -rf .*authority` in my home folder worked.

Comment: What does this command do? I don't like just running `rm` commands.

Comment: Also, does this really need the `r` flag? And the `f` flag?