# Cannot find squid3 service

Tags: services, squid

The service for `squid3` does not exist in `/etc/init.d/`. If I try to stop or start squid3, it does not work.

I tried purging `squid3` and installing again, but to no avail.

Comment: Please review the guide available here: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/squid.html

Comment: of curse this is my first step, but the directory /etc/init.d/squid  no exist!!. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: after sudo apt-get install squid, services of squid no exist

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services

Comment: Check if exists /etc/init/squid3.conf. What release of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: yes, exist squid3.conf. I use ubuntu server 13.1 x86

Comment: So squid3 service is handled by upstart, did you reboot after squid3 installation? try `initctl status squid3` to view its status and post the output, please.

Answer (score 0):

**Did u test the service using sudo?**
Explain: You can check apache2 service without sudo, but you can't check for status of the service squid3 withoud root or sudo.