# How can I make Ubuntu to run only one application on startup

Tags: 12.04, python, raspberrypi

I am currently developing a quad copter controller that is touch screen and powered by Raspberry Pi. I already know how to program using Python, but I am having trouble making it run my only app on start up...any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You may want to look at this post for further information http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd follow these instructions
[How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

I think the easiest way is to figure out a terminal command that can run your program. Then from your dash search for startup applications. Click the add button. Copy the command where it says command and then save that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... will i also be able to load graphical UI

Comment: I see no reason why you wouldn't. Startup applications just starts the program. If that program happens to have a GUI, then that should be what comes up.

Comment: Oh ok great. i am a recent convert to linux lol

Comment: In that case: Welcome!