# How to stop all services except ssh?

Tags: server, ssh, services

In command line, how can I stop all services from my Ubuntu (Server in this particular case), except SSH?

And how can I list all services to be sure all of them were stopped?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable or disable services?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Comment: I seriously doubt you want to stop all services but ssh.

Comment: I am doing an operation that is extremely low level and, yes, I need to do *exactly* this.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called single user mode.  It is a state where only the bare essential services required for the machine to run are running.  You enter it either by booting with an 's' argument given to the kernel, or you can switch to it using `init s`.  `sshd` is not normally considered an essential service though, so it would be stopped.  To fix this, you need to edit /etc/init/ssh.conf and add an 'S' to the list of runlevels it should start in and not be stopped in, so it looks like this:

```
start on runlevel [S12345]
stop on runlevel [!S12345]
```

Comment: Instead of editing `ssh.conf`, use an [Upstart override file](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files).

Comment: @muru, good point

Answer (score 3):

I seriously doubt that your system will be still in a useful state after disabling everything but sshd. 
For a status list of upstart services do:

```
sudo service --status-all
```

For System V services:

```
sudo initctl list
```

Disable anything that has a + or is listed as start/running with the appropriate commands. To state the blatantly obvious: if you do this via ssh "service network stop" or the like won't do you any good.

Comment: Believe me, I need to do *exactly* this.

Comment: You do realize that SSH is of no use to you, without the network service?

Comment: Of course I assume you know what you're about to do (and wish good luck), but I think the warning had to be given for others reading this.