# How to disable webmin start on boot on Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, webmin

How to disable Webmin starts on boot on Ubuntu 14? Due security reasons, I want to run it manualy when I really will use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable or disable services?](http://askubuntu.com/q/19320/216503). Also please mention the correct release of Ubuntu.

Comment: I dont see the answere there.I tried with /etc/rc.local to add
`service webmin stop` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable Webmin starting at boot from the Webmin interface, in the Webmin Configuration module. At the bottom of the module window is the option to set when Webmin starts. You can invoke Webmin to start via command-line `sudo service webmin start` when configured not to start at boot.

Answer (score 2):

You can either manually edit the scripts but the best way is to run

```
sudo update-rc.d webmin enable
```

and all the required entries will be made cleanly - less risk of breakage of essential startup scripts.

and the reverse to disable

```
sudo update-rc.d webmin disable
```