# Cannot stop nginx service

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, server, upstart, nginx

It took me a while to find out, but as of some recent-ish update, I can't stop Nginx on any of my Ubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 14.04 servers.

I run `sudo service nginx stop`, and I get `nginx start/running, process 16178`.

I try `sudo service nginx stop` again, and I get `nginx start/running, process 16206`.

Note how the process number changes.

In `/var/log/syslog` I can see why:

`Jun 11 11:57:51 kernel: [2318556.994508] init: nginx main process ended, respawning`.

Nginx is respawned every time I run `sudo service nginx stop`. It never comes to a full stop.

I tried updating Ubuntu, rebooted and I re-installed my servers on local test-images (I use Puppet). Nothing makes any difference. I also tried searching for bugs relating to this without avail.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? I'd like to be able to run `sudo service nginx stop` and have all nginx processes stopped as a result.

Comment: Are you using a PPA for `nginx`? The packages for `nginx` in Ubuntu at least upto 14.04 use sysv init scripts, not Upstart init files. The `respawn` option is an Upstart thing, and neither Ubuntu's package for `nginx` nor the nginx team's PPA (https://launchpad.net/~nginx/+archive/ubuntu/stable) use Upstart.

Comment: I'm using ppa:nginx/stable on 12.04 and 14.04

Answer (score 4):

It seems you nginx server is handle by an upstart process.

Look in the /etc/init folder, and check if there is not a file which handles nginx.

```
grep -r nginx /etc/init
```

Then edit this file, and remove the `respawn` option in the config file.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to try your solution when I noticed that it now works. I'm guessing some update solved the problem? Or maybe it was a reboot.

In any case, this answer is helpful to me as it will help me find the problem should it resurface.

Comment: It's work, for e too. Additionally, I follow the instructions in http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services to avoid it automatically starts.

Answer (score 4):

You can stop nginx process using `sudo nginx -s quit`

You can see in `/etc/init/nginx`

Comment: "sudo nginx -s quit" solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I wanted to update my letsencrypt certificates with a temporary webserver by `certbot`: every time, i stopped nginx with

```
service stop nginx
```

after some seconds it restarted automatically so when it came to serving the proof of my domain certbot, port 443 was already in use by the respawned nginx.

I was really in a hurry to fix this, so I started a really dirty workaround, but it worked:

```
while true; do service nginx stop; sleep 2; done
```

Now I was able to refresh my certificates and find out later, how to stop nginx for good in a more correct way ;)

Comment: jeez, so how did you do this the correct way?