# Unable to kill process Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to kill processes on port 80. Here are the process running on port 80

```
lsof -i tcp:80
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   6233    root   13u  IPv4 4216925      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   6235 opscode   13u  IPv4 4216925      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

I have tried killing processes using `kill -9 <PID>` but they still exist with PID changed. How can I kill the processes forcefully?

Comment: Try `sudo pkill nginx`

Comment: This maybe an duplicate of this question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/635110/cannot-stop-nginx-service

Answer (score 0):

Use the `pkill` command since you know the command name.

```
sudo pkill -f nginx
```

`-f:`

```
   The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.
      When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```