# During system restart telnet service isn't start automatically

Tags: restart, automation, telnet

Each time i restart the system i need to login through SSH & then restart the telnet service manually. Any idea how to get rid of this?
`System Info:
Ubuntu 15.04 (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-36-generic x86_64)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add it to startup.
[How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/q/19320/238149)
This answer here explains how to do that.