# How can I stop mongodb from starting on system boot

Tags: startup, upstart, autostart

I installed mongodb for learning purpose, the problem I am facing is that it starts on system boot and consume resources even if not being used. I want it to be removed from system boot, how can I do this?

Comment: From how much resources are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable or disable services?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Comment: If you are using a recent version of ubuntu, you probably need to follow the instructions for systemd on how to "disable" a service: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services?noredirect=1&lq=1 ; you can also "mask" a service if you want to *completely* disable the service. If you "disable" a service it will not automatically start at boot time. If you "mask" a service, it will not be able to be started and will be *completely* disabled.

Answer (score 18):

I can't test it at the moment, but I think this should work

```
 sudo update-rc.d mongodb disable
```

If this is not enough try this

```
 sudo update-rc.d -f mongodb remove
```

Comment: Yep, the first one worked to me :)

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me and I'm using Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo systemctl disable mongod
```

Comment: With mongodb version v3.6.8 on linux mint 20 the service is called `mongodb` (and not just `mongod`), so I can disable it with `sudo systemctl disable mongodb`.

Answer (score 6):

This is borrowed from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19324/139755):

```
echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/mongod.override
```

Comment: As Robert indicated in his answer, this works but the file should be `mongod.override` (not mongodb)

Answer (score 4):

@davelupt's reference is great. However I guess the command should be

`echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/mongod.override`

since the file for MongoDB under /etc/init is `mongod.conf`.

Comment: On 16.10 and 16.04, I'm showing `/etc/init/mongodb.conf` when I run either one of the following commands: `dpkg -L mongodb-server | grep /etc/init/mongod` or `apt-file search /etc/init/mongod`

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18 and above use

```
$ sudo systemctl stop mongod
```

For earlier versions

```
$ sudo service mongod stop
```

For MacOS:

```
$ brew services stop mongodb-community@4.2
```

For Windows, Open CMD as Admin:

```
sc.exe delete MongoDB
```

More info can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/)