# 16.04 Command to list all services started on boot

Tags: 16.04, command-line, systemd

I've installed mongodb v3.4. This starts up on boot.

So I'm wondering, how to I find out what is starting this up (and how to disable it from starting on boot)?

The following did not work:

[How can I stop mongodb from starting on system boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/677066/how-can-i-stop-mongodb-from-starting-on-system-boot) (old)

[Command to list services that start on startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218/command-to-list-services-that-start-on-startup) (old)

Comment: `service --status-all` list all the services. You can refer [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220852/ubuntu-full-list-of-available-services)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As far as I now, services are automatically enabled in Ubuntu, so when you install something like `Apache` it will be started at boot.

#### Find some information

To find out all services that have been run at startup:

```
systemctl list-units --type service
```

this will show all services that has been loaded at boot and are active now.
If you want to get a list of all services no matter they are active or not:

```
systemctl list-units --type service --all
```

Another thing you can do is to run:

```
systemctl list-dependencies --type service
```

then hit `/` and search for `mongodb` see what `service`/`target` depends on it and runs it.

Also you can run :

```
locate mongodb.service
```

Which produces something like:

```
/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mongodb.service
```

then you will know that it's being started as a part of multi-user target, alternative to this is:

```
$ systemctl cat mongodb.service | grep -i wantedby
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

#### Disable it

To find out that if it's active (Will be run at startup/boot-time):

```
systemctl is-active mongodb
```

It's either `active` or `inactive`; In your case it should be `active`.

To stop it from being started at boot time we should disable it:

```
sudo systemctl disable mongodb
```

And to make sure nothing else (No other service) can start it, we mask it:

```
systemctl mask mongodb
```

so it will be linked to `/dev/null` and can't be started automatically or manually anymore.

*I'm not aware of `mongodb` service name, try hitting the tab it will be completed. I guess it's `mongodb` ;)*

Comment: `systemctl list-units --type service` will not show users services. Wondering is there a way to show all = system and all users services ?

Comment: sudo update-rc.d mongodb disable

Answer (score 14):

To know if a service is enabled at boot time, the right command is :

```
systemctl is-enabled apache2
enabled
```

You can try by yourself by changing the state with

```
systemctl enable apache2
systemctl disable apache2
```

(this isn't intended to be the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at Settings -> Session and Startup -> Application Autostart to see if your application is mentioned there.